# How to create a android.net.Uri from a java.net.URL?

Tags: java, android

I would like to `use intent.setData(Uri uri)` to pass data obtained from a URL.  In order to do this, I need to be able to create a Uri from a URL (or from a byte[] I read from the URL, or a `ByteArrayInputStream` I create from the `byte[]`, etc).  However, I cannot figure out how this is supposed to be done.

So, is there anyway to create a Uri from data obtained from a URL without first writing the data to a local file?

Answer (score 42):

Use [`URL.toURI()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#toURI%28%29) ([Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#toURI%28%29)) method.

Example:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com"); //Some instantiated URL object
URI uri = url.toURI();
```

Make sure to handle relevant exception, such as [`URISyntaxException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URISyntaxException.html).

Comment: toURI returns "URI" from net package, setData method needs "Uri"

Comment: This does not take into account the special characters that a parameter might have.

Comment: @QualtarDemix that is not what was asked by the OP. I provided a solution based on this requirement.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi: Well that is implicit. The idea is to get the best possible solution. Even if that wasn't explicitly asked.

Comment: Suppose **http** is not part of the url string?

Answer (score 13):

I think your answer can be found from here..

`Uri.Builder.build()` works quite well with normal URLs, but it fails with port number support.

The easiest way that I discovered to make it support port numbers was to make it parse a given URL first then work with it.

```
Uri.Builder b = Uri.parse("http://www.yoursite.com:12345").buildUpon();

b.path("/path/to/something/");
b.appendQueryParameter("arg1", String.valueOf(42));

if (username != "") {
  b.appendQueryParameter("username", username);
}

String url = b.build().toString();
```

Source : http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2011/01/android-create-url-using.html

Comment: Also, instead of hardcoding "http://...", you could use `yourUrlVariable.toString()` instead.

Answer (score 11):

From [How to create a Uri from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240139/how-to-create-a-uri-from-a-url)

```
Uri uri =  Uri.parse( "http://www.facebook.com" );
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that in Android, Uri's are different from Java URI's.  Here's how to avoid using hardcoded strings, and at the same time, create a Uri with just the path portion of the http URL string encoded to conform to RFC2396:

Sample Url String:

```
String thisUrl = "http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=[redacted]&mapid=value"
```

method:

```
private Uri.Builder builder;
public Uri getUriFromUrl(String thisUrl) {
    URL url = new URL(thisUrl);
    builder =  new Uri.Builder()
                            .scheme(url.getProtocol())
                            .authority(url.getAuthority())
                            .appendPath(url.getPath());
    return builder.build();
}
```

To handle query strings you will need to parse the url.getQuery() as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13592567/923920) and then feed that into builder. appendQueryParameter().

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
    uri = new URI(url.toString());
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
}
```

Comment: Cannot instantiate the type Uri