# Parse a URI String into Name-Value Collection

Tags: java, parsing, uri, namevaluecollection

I've got the URI like this:

```
https://google.com.ua/oauth/authorize?client_id=SS&response_type=code&scope=N_FULL&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost/Callback
```

I need a collection with parsed elements:

```
NAME               VALUE
------------------------
client_id          SS
response_type      code
scope              N_FULL
access_type        offline
redirect_uri       http://localhost/Callback
```

To be exact, I need a Java equivalent for the C#/.NET [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?view=netcore-3.1) method.

Comment: Please check this solution - solid library and working example for both Parse and Format operations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37744000/1882064

Answer (score 421, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to achieve it without using an external library, the following code will help you.

```
public static Map<String, String> splitQuery(URL url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Map<String, String> query_pairs = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    String query = url.getQuery();
    String[] pairs = query.split("&");
    for (String pair : pairs) {
        int idx = pair.indexOf("=");
        query_pairs.put(URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), "UTF-8"), URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), "UTF-8"));
    }
    return query_pairs;
}
```

You can access the returned Map using `<map>.get("client_id")`, with the URL given in your question this would return "SS".

**UPDATE**  URL-Decoding added

**UPDATE** As this answer is still quite popular, I made an improved version of the method above, which handles multiple parameters with the same key and parameters with no value as well.

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> splitQuery(URL url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
  final Map<String, List<String>> query_pairs = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
  final String[] pairs = url.getQuery().split("&");
  for (String pair : pairs) {
    final int idx = pair.indexOf("=");
    final String key = idx > 0 ? URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), "UTF-8") : pair;
    if (!query_pairs.containsKey(key)) {
      query_pairs.put(key, new LinkedList<String>());
    }
    final String value = idx > 0 && pair.length() > idx + 1 ? URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), "UTF-8") : null;
    query_pairs.get(key).add(value);
  }
  return query_pairs;
}
```

**UPDATE** Java8 version

```
public Map<String, List<String>> splitQuery(URL url) {
    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(url.getQuery())) {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }
    return Arrays.stream(url.getQuery().split("&"))
            .map(this::splitQueryParameter)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SimpleImmutableEntry::getKey, LinkedHashMap::new, mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())));
}

public SimpleImmutableEntry<String, String> splitQueryParameter(String it) {
    final int idx = it.indexOf("=");
    final String key = idx > 0 ? it.substring(0, idx) : it;
    final String value = idx > 0 && it.length() > idx + 1 ? it.substring(idx + 1) : null;
    return new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(
        URLDecoder.decode(key, StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
        URLDecoder.decode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    );
}
```

Running the above method with the URL

`https://stackoverflow.com?param1=value1&param2=&param3=value3&param3`

returns this Map:

```
{param1=["value1"], param2=[null], param3=["value3", null]}
```

Comment: You are forgetting to decode the names and parameters, one reason why it's usually better to let libraries do common tasks.

Comment: My answer points out a commonly used library (apache), if you are not already using it, it's probably not worth it. The answer looks good now and provides the map the OP would like

Comment: yeah .. of course, if I already need to use the specific library for other tasks, I'll use the provided methods instead of wasting time writing my own method.

Comment: if you have multiple parameters with same name/key, using this function will override the value that has similar key.

Comment: @snowball147 you could replace `query_pairs.put()` by a handling function or use a `Map<String, List<String>>`. For the second case amend the for to contain e.g. `int idx = pair.indexOf("=");
            final String key = URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), "UTF-8");
            final String value = URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(
                    idx + 1), "UTF-8");
            if(!query_pairs.containsKey(key)) {
                query_pairs.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
            }
            query_pairs.get(key).add(value);`

Comment: This also doesn't handle the case where the key doesn't have a value

Comment: I didn't know there could be multiple parameters with the same key.  In this case, what does HttpServletRequest.getParameter() returns?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Read the docs `You should only use this method when you are sure the parameter has only one value. If the parameter might have more than one value, use getParameterValues(java.lang.String).` http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work right with encoded &'s (&amp;). 

For example it breaks on this url: http://a.com/q?1=a&amp;b&2=b&amp;c

The output of that should be
{1=a&b, 2=b&c}

Comment: @Chris You're confusing xml/html escaping with URL encoding.  Your example URL should be: a.com/q?1=a%26b&2=b%26c

Comment: If you have "#" in your url - URL.getQuery() return null and this solution will not work

Comment: It should be `it.length() >= idx + 1` so that "a=&b=&c=" is parsed to {"a",""},{"b",""} and {"c",""}

Comment: @Pr0gr4mm3r I edited your answer to add the null checks also for the first two solutions. Note that for "http://www.example.com" `getQuery()` returns null, instead for "http://www.example.com?" it returns an empty String.

Comment: it would be nice to indicate which functions are used: Collectors.mapping(...) and Collectors.toList(...)

Comment: Hi, it would be great if someone could update this solution with the required imports for everything, as intellij, doest have a feature to go find the imports (at least doesnt work for me). E.g. these cant be resolved: MAP, URL, UnsupportedEncodingException, URLDecoder

Comment: Ready-to-use solution (with imports) that handles multi values, parameter decoding and error handling can be found below ( see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58017826/1211082 )  ( @John Little )

Comment: @Pr0gr4mm3r great example! :) Could I use the same code for parsing a normal commanline string what has different parameters and values and looks like: t=s vo="bin\\house_1.xml" u=30?

Comment: Simply avoiding UnsupportedEncodingException:
...
    return new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(URLDecoder.decode(key, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), URLDecoder.decode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
...

Comment: Wouldnt this fail on param1=par&myparam&param2=param2? unless you have a url encoded query string already...

Answer (score 403):

## [org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-5.1.x/current/httpcore5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/core5/net/URLEncodedUtils.html)

is a well known library that can do it for you

```
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.utils.URLEncodedUtils

String url = "http://www.example.com/something.html?one=1&two=2&three=3&three=3a";

List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

for (NameValuePair param : params) {
  System.out.println(param.getName() + " : " + param.getValue());
}
```

Outputs

```
one : 1
two : 2
three : 3
three : 3a
```

Comment: Can I receive the value by it's name without passing all the elements? I mean something like this:
System.out.print(params["one"]);

Comment: @SergeyShafiev It is trivial to convert a `List<NameValuePair>` into a `Map<String,String>` Java doesn't have bracket access for hash maps, it would look like `map.get("one")` If you don't know how to do that, it should be another question (but try it on your own first). We prefer to keep questions slim here at SO

Comment: Be careful that if you have two times the same parameter in your URL (i.e. ?a=1&a=2) URLEncodedUtils will throw an IllegalArgumentException

Comment: @Crystark As of httpclient 4.3.3, query string with duplicated names does not throw any exceptions. It works as expected. `System.out.println(URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI("http://example.com/?foo=bar&foo=baz"), "UTF-8"));` will print _[foo=bar, foo=baz]_.

Comment: As of Android 6, the Apache HTTP client library has been removed. This means `URLEncodedUtils and `NameValuePair` are no longer available (unless you add a dependency to the legacy Apache library as described [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)).

Comment: Please check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37744000/1882064 which shows details on how to use the referenced URLEncodedUtils lib.

Comment: Note that HttpClient will fail to parse a query component like this one `foo=bár`.

Answer (score 163):

If you are using Spring Framework:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String uri = "http://my.test.com/test?param1=ab&param2=cd&param2=ef";
    MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters =
            UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(uri).build().getQueryParams();
    List<String> param1 = parameters.get("param1");
    List<String> param2 = parameters.get("param2");
    System.out.println("param1: " + param1.get(0));
    System.out.println("param2: " + param2.get(0) + "," + param2.get(1));
}
```

You will get:

```
param1: ab
param2: cd,ef
```

Comment: for URLs use `UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)`

Comment: Beware that `getQueryParams()` does **not** decode the query parameters. So for a URL of `http://foobar/path?param1=a%3Db` you get `param1: a%3Db` and not `param1: a=b`. You need to use `URLDecoder.decode()` yourself... - `getQueryParams()` is **BROKEN**.

Comment: what if the param1=H&M, it doesn't parse if the parameter value itself has an ampersand(&)

Answer (score 60):

use google Guava and do it in 2 lines:

```
import java.util.Map;
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;

public class Parser {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String uri = "https://google.com.ua/oauth/authorize?client_id=SS&response_type=code&scope=N_FULL&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost/Callback";
        String query = uri.split("\\?")[1];
        final Map<String, String> map = Splitter.on('&').trimResults().withKeyValueSeparator('=').split(query);
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

which gives you

```
{client_id=SS, response_type=code, scope=N_FULL, access_type=offline, redirect_uri=http://localhost/Callback}
```

Comment: What about the URL decoding described in the selected answer?

Comment: Almost, there, right? That's going to give you the protocol+host+path on the first query parameter's name. And, a minor nit, withKeyValueSeparator() doesn't accept char. Needs to be String

Comment: This is also suspect to multiple keys with the same name. According to the javadocs this will throw an IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Also I would suggest to use .withKeyValueSeparator('=') . String as parameter is unnecessary cost compared to character.

Comment: Instead of manually splitting `uri` you should use `new java.net.URL(uri).getQuery()` as this buys you free input validation on the URL.

Comment: For decoding:

    final Map<String, String> queryVars = Maps.transformValues(map, new  Function<String,String>() {

   @Override
   public String apply(String value) {
    try {
     return URLDecoder.decode(value, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return value;
   }
         
        });

Comment: @rkosegi, char-parameterized Splitter constructor creates string from char internally, so the one which more effective is String-parameterized

Comment: @KirillGamazkov : nobody should rely on internal implementation details. Passing a string literal will create instance of String (by compiler) where char is primitive type.

Comment: @rkosegi, it's incorrect to say that one method more effective than another without digging into implementations

Comment: WARNING!!  It's NOT safe to do this since `splitter.split()` will throw `IllegalArgumentException` if there're duplicate key in query string. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746507/authoritative-position-of-duplicate-http-get-query-keys

Comment: In my case, the URL is safely controlled, so this is a nice fast way. Thanks.

Comment: `url.split("\\?")[1].split(";")[0]` because cut cookie

Comment: Thanks you i use guava split

Comment: Beware that this solution would throw in case some value has extra '=' inside. Here is the workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37402817/603516

Answer (score 50):

The shortest way I've found is this one:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams =
            UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url).build().getQueryParams();
```

**UPDATE:** `UriComponentsBuilder` comes from Spring. Here [the link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html).

Comment: Without knowing where this UriComponentsBuilder class come from it's not very useful.

Comment: **N.B.** This takes URIs. Java's version of URIs are not a superset of URLs (this is why toURI can throw exceptions).

Comment: Beware that `getQueryParams()` does **not** decode the query parameters. So for a URL of `http://foobar/path?param1=a%3Db` you get `param1: a%3Db` and not `param1: a=b`. You need to use `URLDecoder.decode()` yourself... - `getQueryParams()` is **BROKEN**.

Comment: Also, if the URL comes from an HTML document, you must unescape it first: `org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils.htmlUnescape(myUrl)`

Comment: This will fail with "param=value". You will have to include the starting '?'

Answer (score 36):

For Android, if you are using [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) in your project. You might get a look at this. It simple and helpful.

```
final HttpUrl url = HttpUrl.parse(query);
if (url != null) {
    final String target = url.queryParameter("target");
    final String id = url.queryParameter("id");
}
```

Comment: HttpUrl is kind of a weird name but this is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: update: `HttpUrl.parse()` is deprecated as of OkHttp 4, but this is still possible with the new OkHttp extension function described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63118203/2888763

Answer (score 24):

## PLAIN Java 11

Given the URL to analyse:

```java
URL url = new URL("https://google.com.ua/oauth/authorize?client_id=SS&response_type=code&scope=N_FULL&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost/Callback");
```

This solution collects a list of pairs:

```java
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> list = Pattern.compile("&")
   .splitAsStream(url.getQuery())
   .map(s -> Arrays.copyOf(s.split("=", 2), 2))
   .map(o -> Map.entry(decode(o[0]), decode(o[1])))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This solution on the other hand collects a map (given that in a url there can be more parameters with same name but different values).

```java
Map<String, List<String>> list = Pattern.compile("&")
   .splitAsStream(url.getQuery())
   .map(s -> Arrays.copyOf(s.split("=", 2), 2))
   .collect(groupingBy(s -> decode(s[0]), mapping(s -> decode(s[1]), toList())));
```

Both the solutions must use an utility function to properly decode the parameters.

```java
private static String decode(final String encoded) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(encoded)
                   .map(e -> URLDecoder.decode(e, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                   .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: This is more a Java 8 *approach* rather than a Java 8 oneliner.

Comment: @Stephan well :) maybe both. But I'm more interested to understand if you like this solution.

Comment: IMO, a oneliner should be short and shouldn't span over multiple lines.

Comment: IMO a oneliner is when it is a single statement. I wrote in this way for readability.

Comment: There are multiple statements involved here.

Comment: I've double checked, this is a statement. Have a look at [Expressions, Statements, and Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)

Comment: The solutions must use an utility function. So there are more than one statements involved.

Comment: I guess I would call these statements: two oneliners that have a depenpency to an utility function :)

Comment: One liner is one line, this is a multiline statement

Comment: I guess you could write a whole class on a single line, but that's not what is usually meant by the phrase "one-liner".

Comment: One slight improvement if you happen to have Java 10 or higher - URLDecoder#decode (finally) has an overload that takes a Charset (e.g. StandardCharsets.UTF_8) instead of a string for the encoding, meaning you don't need to catch UnsupportedEncodingException.

Comment: @AhmadShahwan as far as I remember, it was an ugly trick to be sure split() returns always an array of two elements (even if split() was unable to find the matching string =)

Answer (score 15):

On Android, there is a Uri class in package ***android.net*** . Note that **Uri** is part of **android.net**, whereas **URI** is part of **java.net** .

Uri class has many functions to extract key-value pairs from a query.
[image]

Following function returns key-value pairs in the form of HashMap.

In Java:

```
Map<String, String> getQueryKeyValueMap(Uri uri){
    HashMap<String, String> keyValueMap = new HashMap();
    String key;
    String value;

    Set<String> keyNamesList = uri.getQueryParameterNames();
    Iterator iterator = keyNamesList.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        key = (String) iterator.next();
        value = uri.getQueryParameter(key);
        keyValueMap.put(key, value);
    }
    return keyValueMap;
}
```

In Kotlin:

```
fun getQueryKeyValueMap(uri: Uri): HashMap<String, String> {
        val keyValueMap = HashMap<String, String>()
        var key: String
        var value: String

        val keyNamesList = uri.queryParameterNames
        val iterator = keyNamesList.iterator()

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            key = iterator.next() as String
            value = uri.getQueryParameter(key) as String
            keyValueMap.put(key, value)
        }
        return keyValueMap
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

[Netty](https://netty.io/) also provides a nice query string parser called `QueryStringDecoder`.
In one line of code, it can parse the URL in the question.
I like because it doesn't require catching or throwing `java.net.MalformedURLException`.

In one line:

```
Map<String, List<String>> parameters = new QueryStringDecoder(url).parameters();
```

See javadocs here: https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/QueryStringDecoder.html

Here is a short, self contained, correct example:

```
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.QueryStringDecoder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class UrlParse {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    String url = "https://google.com.ua/oauth/authorize?client_id=SS&response_type=code&scope=N_FULL&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost/Callback";
    QueryStringDecoder decoder = new QueryStringDecoder(url);
    Map<String, List<String>> parameters = decoder.parameters();
    print(parameters);
  }

  private static void print(final Map<String, List<String>> parameters) {
    System.out.println("NAME               VALUE");
    System.out.println("------------------------");
    parameters.forEach((key, values) ->
        values.forEach(val ->
            System.out.println(StringUtils.rightPad(key, 19) + val)));
  }
}
```

which generates

```
NAME               VALUE
------------------------
client_id          SS
response_type      code
scope              N_FULL
access_type        offline
redirect_uri       http://localhost/Callback
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are using servlet doGet try this

```
request.getParameterMap()
```

> *Returns a java.util.Map of the parameters of this request.*
>
> *Returns:
>   an immutable java.util.Map containing parameter names as keys and parameter values as map values. The keys in the parameter map are of type String. The values in the parameter map are of type String array.*
>
> ([Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()))

Comment: This works with Spring Web as well as in your controller you can have a parameter of type `HttpServletRequest` and it works with `MockHttpServletRequest` as well in Mock MVC unit tests.

Comment: This is good unless you also want to do request.getInputStream(). getInputStream() may or may not work after a call get getParameterMap(). It's implementation dependent.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Java 8 and you're willing to write a few reusable methods, you can do it in one line.

```
private Map<String, List<String>> parse(final String query) {
    return Arrays.asList(query.split("&")).stream().map(p -> p.split("=")).collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> decode(index(s, 0)), s -> Arrays.asList(decode(index(s, 1))), this::mergeLists));
}

private <T> List<T> mergeLists(final List<T> l1, final List<T> l2) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.addAll(l1);
    list.addAll(l2);
    return list;
}

private static <T> T index(final T[] array, final int index) {
    return index >= array.length ? null : array[index];
}

private static String decode(final String encoded) {
    try {
        return encoded == null ? null : URLDecoder.decode(encoded, "UTF-8");
    } catch(final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Impossible: UTF-8 is a required encoding", e);
    }
}
```

But that's a pretty brutal line.

Answer (score 5):

There a new version of Apache HTTP client - `org.apache.httpcomponents.client5` - where `URLEncodedUtils` is now deprecated. `URIBuilder` should be used instead:

```
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.hc.core5.net.URIBuilder;

private static Map<String, String> getQueryParameters(final String url) throws URISyntaxException {
    return new URIBuilder(new URI(url), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).getQueryParams()
                                                               .stream()
                                                               .collect(Collectors.toMap(NameValuePair::getName,
                                                                                         nameValuePair -> URLDecoder.decode(nameValuePair.getValue(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## A ready-to-use solution for decoding of URI query part (incl. decoding and multi parameter values)

### Comments

I wasn't happy with the code provided by @Pr0gr4mm3r in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13592567/1211082 . The Stream-based solution does not do URLDecoding, the mutable version clumpsy.

Thus I elaborated a solution that

- Can decompose a URI query part into a `Map<String, List<Optional<String>>>`
- Can **handle multiple values** for the same parameter name
- Can **represent parameters without a value properly**  (`Optional.empty()` instead of `null`)
- **Decodes parameter names** and **values correctly** via `URLdecode`
- Is based on Java 8 Streams
- Is directly usable (see code including imports below)
- Allows for proper error handling (here via turning a checked exception `UnsupportedEncodingException`into a runtime exception `RuntimeUnsupportedEncodingException` that allows interplay with stream. (Wrapping regular function into functions throwing checked exceptions is a pain. And Scala `Try` is not available in the Java language default.)

### Java Code

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

public class URIParameterDecode {
    /**
     * Decode parameters in query part of a URI into a map from parameter name to its parameter values.
     * For parameters that occur multiple times each value is collected.
     * Proper decoding of the parameters is performed.
     * 
     * Example
     *   <pre>a=1&b=2&c=&a=4</pre>
     * is converted into
     *   <pre>{a=[Optional[1], Optional[4]], b=[Optional[2]], c=[Optional.empty]}</pre>
     * @param query the query part of an URI 
     * @return map of parameters names into a list of their values.
     *         
     */
    public static Map<String, List<Optional<String>>> splitQuery(String query) {
        if (query == null || query.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptyMap();
        }

        return Arrays.stream(query.split("&"))
                    .map(p -> splitQueryParameter(p))
                    .collect(groupingBy(e -> e.get0(), // group by parameter name
                            mapping(e -> e.get1(), toList())));// keep parameter values and assemble into list
    }

    public static Pair<String, Optional<String>> splitQueryParameter(String parameter) {
        final String enc = "UTF-8";
        List<String> keyValue = Arrays.stream(parameter.split("="))
                .map(e -> {
                    try {
                        return URLDecoder.decode(e, enc);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                        throw new RuntimeUnsupportedEncodingException(ex);
                    }
                }).collect(toList());

        if (keyValue.size() == 2) {
            return new Pair(keyValue.get(0), Optional.of(keyValue.get(1)));
        } else {
            return new Pair(keyValue.get(0), Optional.empty());
        }
    }

    /** Runtime exception (instead of checked exception) to denote unsupported enconding */
    public static class RuntimeUnsupportedEncodingException extends RuntimeException {
        public RuntimeUnsupportedEncodingException(Throwable cause) {
            super(cause);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A simple pair of two elements
     * @param <U> first element
     * @param <V> second element
     */
    public static class Pair<U, V> {
        U a;
        V b;

        public Pair(U u, V v) {
            this.a = u;
            this.b = v;
        }

        public U get0() {
            return a;
        }

        public V get1() {
            return b;
        }
    }
}
```

### Scala Code

... and for the sake of completeness I can not resist to provide the solution in Scala that dominates by brevity and beauty

```
import java.net.URLDecoder

object Decode {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val input = "a=1&b=2&c=&a=4";
    println(separate(input))
  }

  def separate(input: String) : Map[String, List[Option[String]]] = {
    case class Parameter(key: String, value: Option[String])

    def separateParameter(parameter: String) : Parameter =
      parameter.split("=")
               .map(e => URLDecoder.decode(e, "UTF-8")) match {
      case Array(key, value) =>  Parameter(key, Some(value))
      case Array(key) => Parameter(key, None)
    }

    input.split("&").toList
      .map(p => separateParameter(p))
      .groupBy(p => p.key)
      .mapValues(vs => vs.map(p => p.value))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using above mentioned comments and solutions, I am storing all the query parameters using Map<String, Object> where Objects either can be string or Set<String>. The solution is given below. It is recommended to use some kind of url validator to validate the url first and then call convertQueryStringToMap method.

```
private static final String DEFAULT_ENCODING_SCHEME = "UTF-8";

public static Map<String, Object> convertQueryStringToMap(String url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, URISyntaxException {
    List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url), DEFAULT_ENCODING_SCHEME);
    Map<String, Object> queryStringMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(NameValuePair param : params){
        queryStringMap.put(param.getName(), handleMultiValuedQueryParam(queryStringMap, param.getName(), param.getValue()));
    }
    return queryStringMap;
}

private static Object handleMultiValuedQueryParam(Map responseMap, String key, String value) {
    if (!responseMap.containsKey(key)) {
        return value.contains(",") ? new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(value.split(","))) : value;
    } else {
        Set<String> queryValueSet = responseMap.get(key) instanceof Set ? (Set<String>) responseMap.get(key) : new HashSet<String>();
        if (value.contains(",")) {
            queryValueSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(value.split(",")));
        } else {
            queryValueSet.add(value);
        }
        return queryValueSet;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Set` is the wrong data type for the use cases where parameter order is important.

Answer (score 2):

I had a go at a Kotlin version seeing how this is the top result in Google.

```
@Throws(UnsupportedEncodingException::class)
fun splitQuery(url: URL): Map<String, List<String>> {

    val queryPairs = LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>()

    url.query.split("&".toRegex())
            .dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }
            .map { it.split('=') }
            .map { it.getOrEmpty(0).decodeToUTF8() to it.getOrEmpty(1).decodeToUTF8() }
            .forEach { (key, value) ->

                if (!queryPairs.containsKey(key)) {
                    queryPairs[key] = arrayListOf(value)
                } else {

                    if(!queryPairs[key]!!.contains(value)) {
                        queryPairs[key]!!.add(value)
                    }
                }
            }

    return queryPairs
}
```

And the extension methods

```
fun List<String>.getOrEmpty(index: Int) : String {
    return getOrElse(index) {""}
}

fun String.decodeToUTF8(): String { 
    URLDecoder.decode(this, "UTF-8")
}
```

Comment: Equal credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1203812/matthew-herod 50/50 effort but can't co-author.

Answer (score 2):

Also, I would recommend regex based implementation of `URLParser`

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class URLParser {
    private final String query;
    
    public URLParser(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }
    
    public String get(String name) {
        String regex = "(?:^|\\?|&)" + name + "=(.*?)(?:&|$)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(this.query);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.group(1);
        }
        
        return "";
    }
}
```

This class is easy to use. It just needs the URL or the query string on initialization and parses value by given key.

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URLParser parser = new URLParser("https://www.google.com/search?q=java+parse+url+params&oq=java+parse+url+params&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i10.18908j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8");
        System.out.println(parser.get("q"));  // java+parse+url+params
        System.out.println(parser.get("sourceid"));  // chrome
        System.out.println(parser.get("ie"));  // UTF-8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin's Answer with initial reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51024552/3286489, but with improved version by tidying up codes and provides 2 versions of it, and use immutable collection operations

Use `java.net.URI` to extract the Query. Then use the below provided extension functions

1. Assuming you only want the last value of query i.e. `page2&page3` will get `{page=3}`, use the below extension function

```
    fun URI.getQueryMap(): Map<String, String> {
        if (query == null) return emptyMap()

        return query.split("&")
                .mapNotNull { element -> element.split("=")
                        .takeIf { it.size == 2 && it.none { it.isBlank() } } }
                .associateBy({ it[0].decodeUTF8() }, { it[1].decodeUTF8() })
    }

    private fun String.decodeUTF8() = URLDecoder.decode(this, "UTF-8") // decode page=%22ABC%22 to page="ABC"
```

2. Assuming you want a list of all value for the query i.e. `page2&page3` will get `{page=[2, 3]}`

```
    fun URI.getQueryMapList(): Map<String, List<String>> {
        if (query == null) return emptyMap()

        return query.split("&")
                .distinct()
                .mapNotNull { element -> element.split("=")
                        .takeIf { it.size == 2 && it.none { it.isBlank() } } }
                .groupBy({ it[0].decodeUTF8() }, { it[1].decodeUTF8() })
    }

    private fun String.decodeUTF8() = URLDecoder.decode(this, "UTF-8") // decode page=%22ABC%22 to page="ABC"
```

The way to use it as below

```
    val uri = URI("schema://host/path/?page=&page=2&page=2&page=3")
    println(uri.getQueryMapList()) // Result is {page=[2, 3]}
    println(uri.getQueryMap()) // Result is {page=3}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of answers which work for your query as you've indicated when it has single parameter definitions. In some  applications it may be useful to handle a few extra query parameter edge cases such as:

- list of parameter values such as `param1&param1=value&param1=` meaning `param1` is set to `List.of("", "value", "")`
- invalid permutations such as `querypath?&=&&=noparamname&`.
- use empty string not null in maps `a=` means "a" is `List.of("")` to match web servlet handling

This uses a Stream with filters and groupingBy to collect to `Map<String, List<String>>`:

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> getParameterValues(URL url) {
    return Arrays.stream(url.getQuery().split("&"))
            .map(s -> s.split("="))
            // filter out empty parameter names (as in Tomcat) "?&=&&=value&":
            .filter(arr -> arr.length > 0 && arr[0].length() > 0)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> URLDecoder.decode(arr[0], StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                     // drop this line for not-name definition order Map:
                     LinkedHashMap::new, 
                     Collectors.mapping(arr -> arr.length < 2 ? "" : URLDecoder.decode(arr[1], StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Collectors.toList())));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### A kotlin version

of the answer [Answer by matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71859427/360327) provided

```
fun decomposeQueryString(query: String, charset: Charset): Map<String, String?> {
   return if (query.split("?").size <= 1)
       emptyMap()
   else {
       query.split("?")[1]
            .split("&")
            .map { it.split(Pattern.compile("="), 2) }
            .associate {
                Pair(
                        URLDecoder.decode(it[0], charset.name()),
                        if (it.size > 1) URLDecoder.decode(it[1], charset.name()) else null
                )
            }
     }
}
```

This takes of the first parameter after the question mark '?' as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring, add an argument of type `@RequestParam Map<String,String>`  to your controller method, and Spring will construct the map for you!

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to the Java 8 version

```
public Map<String, List<String>> splitQuery(URL url) {
    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(url.getQuery())) {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }
    return Arrays.stream(url.getQuery().split("&"))
            .map(this::splitQueryParameter)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SimpleImmutableEntry::getKey, LinkedHashMap::new, **Collectors**.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, **Collectors**.toList())));
}
```

mapping and toList() methods have to be used with Collectors which was not mentioned in the top answer. Otherwise it would throw compilation error in IDE

Comment: looks like you need to also share your `splitQueryParameters()` method? And what's with the `**Collectors**`?

Answer (score 0):

Answering here because this is a popular thread.  This is a clean solution in Kotlin that uses the recommended `UrlQuerySanitizer` api. [See the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/UrlQuerySanitizer).  I have added a string builder to concatenate and display the params.

```
    var myURL: String? = null

    if (intent.hasExtra("my_value")) {
        myURL = intent.extras.getString("my_value")
    } else {
        myURL = intent.dataString
    }

    val sanitizer = UrlQuerySanitizer(myURL)
    // We don't want to manually define every expected query *key*, so we set this to true
    sanitizer.allowUnregisteredParamaters = true
    val parameterNamesToValues: List<UrlQuerySanitizer.ParameterValuePair> = sanitizer.parameterList
    val parameterIterator: Iterator<UrlQuerySanitizer.ParameterValuePair> = parameterNamesToValues.iterator()

    // Helper simply so we can display all values on screen
    val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()

    while (parameterIterator.hasNext()) {
        val parameterValuePair: UrlQuerySanitizer.ParameterValuePair = parameterIterator.next()
        val parameterName: String = parameterValuePair.mParameter
        val parameterValue: String = parameterValuePair.mValue

        // Append string to display all key value pairs
        stringBuilder.append("Key: $parameterName\nValue: $parameterValue\n\n")
    }

    // Set a textView's text to display the string
    val paramListString = stringBuilder.toString()
    val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.activity_title) as TextView
    textView.text = "Paramlist is \n\n$paramListString"

    // to check if the url has specific keys
    if (sanitizer.hasParameter("type")) {
        val type = sanitizer.getValue("type")
        println("sanitizer has type param $type")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with **reduce** and **Optional**:

```
private Optional<SimpleImmutableEntry<String, String>> splitKeyValue(String text) {
    String[] v = text.split("=");
    if (v.length == 1 || v.length == 2) {
        String key = URLDecoder.decode(v[0], StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String value = v.length == 2 ? URLDecoder.decode(v[1], StandardCharsets.UTF_8) : null;
        return Optional.of(new SimpleImmutableEntry<String, String>(key, value));
    } else
        return Optional.empty();
}

private HashMap<String, String> parseQuery(URI uri) {
    HashMap<String, String> params = Arrays.stream(uri.getQuery()
            .split("&"))
            .map(this::splitKeyValue)
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .reduce(
                // initial value
                new HashMap<String, String>(), 
                // accumulator
                (map, kv) -> {
                     map.put(kv.getKey(), kv.getValue()); 
                     return map;
                }, 
                // combiner
                (a, b) -> {
                     a.putAll(b); 
                     return a;
                });
    return params;
}
```

- I ignore duplicate parameters (I take the last one).
- I use `Optional<SimpleImmutableEntry<String, String>>` to ignore garbage later
- The reduction start with an empty map, then populate it on each SimpleImmutableEntry

In case you ask, **reduce** requires this weird combiner in the last parameter, which is only used in parallel streams. Its goal is to merge two intermediate results (here HashMap).

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have cxf-core on the classpath and you know you have no repeated query params, you may want to use [UrlUtils.parseQueryString](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/common/util/UrlUtils.html#parseQueryString-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 0):

The [Eclipse Jersey REST framework](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/) supports this through [`UriComponent`](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/uri/UriComponent.java). Example:

```java
import org.glassfish.jersey.uri.UriComponent;

String uri = "https://google.com.ua/oauth/authorize?client_id=SS&response_type=code&scope=N_FULL&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost/Callback";
MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = UriComponent.decodeQuery(URI.create(uri), true);
for (String key : params.keySet()) {
  System.out.println(key + ": " + params.getFirst(key));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If just want the parameters after the URL from a String. Then the following code will work. I am just assuming the simple Url. I mean no hard and fast checking and decoding. Like in one of my test case I got the Url and I know I just need the value of the paramaters. The url was simple. No encoding decoding needed.

```
String location = "https://google.com.ua/oauth/authorize?client_id=SS&response_type=code&scope=N_FULL&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost/Callback";
String location1 = "https://stackoverflow.com?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3";
String location2 = "https://stackoverflow.com?param1=value1&param2=&param3=value3&param3";
    
    Map<String, String> paramsMap = Stream.of(location)
        .filter(l -> l.indexOf("?") != -1)
        .map(l -> l.substring(l.indexOf("?") + 1, l.length()))
        .flatMap(q -> Pattern.compile("&").splitAsStream(q))
        .map(s -> s.split("="))
        .filter(a -> a.length == 2)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            a -> a[0], 
            a -> a[1],
            (existing, replacement) -> existing + ", " + replacement,
            LinkedHashMap::new
        ));
    
    System.out.println(paramsMap);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That seems tidy to me the best way:

```
static Map<String, String> decomposeQueryString(String query, Charset charset) {
    return Arrays.stream(query.split("&"))
        .map(pair -> pair.split("=", 2))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            pair -> URLDecoder.decode(pair[0], charset),
            pair -> pair.length > 1 ? URLDecoder.decode(pair[1], charset) : null)
        );
}
```

The prerequisite is that your query syntax does not allow repeated parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The [Hutool](https://github.com/dromara/hutool) framework supports this through HttpUtil. Example:

```
import cn.hutool.http.HttpUtil;

    String url ="https://google.com.ua/oauth/authorize?client_id=SS&response_type=code&scope=N_FULL&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost/Callback";
    Map<String, List<String>> stringListMap = HttpUtil.decodeParams(url, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("decodeParams：" + stringListMap);
```

You will get:

```
decodeParams：{client_id=[SS], response_type=[code], scope=[N_FULL], access_type=[offline], redirect_uri=[http://localhost/Callback]}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Plain Java, No Special Libraries, Nothing Fancy**

```
    // assumes you are parsing a line that looks like:
    // /path/resource?key=value&parameter=value
    // which you got from a request header line that looks like:
    // GET /path/resource?key=value&parameter=value HTTP/1.1

    public HashMap<String, String> parseQuery(String path){
        if(path == null || path.isEmpty()){         //basic sanity check
            return null;
        }
        int indexOfQ = path.indexOf("?");           //where the query string starts
        if(indexOfQ == -1){return  null;}           //check query exists
        String queryString = path.substring(indexOfQ + 1);
        String[] queryStringArray = queryString.split("&");
        Map<String, String> kvMap = new HashMap<>();
        for(String kvString : queryStringArray){
            int indexOfE = kvString.indexOf("=");      //check query is formed correctly
            if(indexOfE == -1 || indexOfE == 0){return  null;}
            String[] kvPairArray = kvString.split("=");
            kvMap.put(kvPairArray[0], kvPairArray[1]);
        }

        return kvMap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In groovy

```
    static Map parseQueryParams(String queryString) {
        if(!queryString) return [:]
        queryString.split("&")
            .collect({ it.split("=") })
            .collectEntries { String[] arr ->
                String k = arr.length > 0 ? arr[0] : ""
                String v = arr.length > 1 ? arr[1] : ""
                return [decode(k), decode(v)]
            }
    }

    private static String decode(String s) {
        URLDecoder.decode(s, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is based on the solution above by Dariusz and Pr0gr4mm3r,  but it didn't quite work because their version didn't handle decoding of names/parameters, it also wasn't properly handling situations where a key was defined but no value was defined or when a value was defined but no key defined.  this version essentially tries to match the functionality of the original HttpUtils.parseQueryString() method as much as possible:

```
public Map<String, List<String>> splitQuery(URL url) {
    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(url.getQuery())) {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }
    try {
        String qs = url.getQuery();
        return splitQuery(qs);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        String qs = url.getQuery();
        String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(qs, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return splitQuery(decoded);
    }
}

public Map<String, List<String>> splitQuery(String qs) {
    return Arrays.stream(qs.split("&"))
            .map(this::splitQueryParameter)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::getKey, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
}

public AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<String, String> splitQueryParameter(String it) {
    final int idx = it.indexOf("=");
    if(idx == -1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    final String key = idx > 0 ? it.substring(0, idx) : "";
    final String value = (idx > 0 && it.length() > idx + 1) || (it.indexOf('=') == it.length()-1) || (it.indexOf('=') == 0)  ? it.substring(idx + 1) : it.substring(idx);
    return new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(URLDecoder.decode(key, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), URLDecoder.decode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

JUnit:

```
@Test
public void testSplitQuery2() throws MalformedURLException {
    URL url = new URL("https://google.com.ua/oauth/authorize?client_id=SS&response_type=code&scope=N_FULL&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost/Callback");
    Map<String, List<String>> listMap = splitQuery(url);
    for (String s : listMap.keySet()) {
        List<String> stringList = listMap.get(s);
        logger.info("s: " + s + ", stringList: " + stringList);
    }
}
```

Response:

```
testSplitQuery2 s: client_id, stringList: [SS]                           
testSplitQuery2 s: response_type, stringList: [code]                     
testSplitQuery2 s: scope, stringList: [N_FULL]                           
testSplitQuery2 s: access_type, stringList: [offline]                    
testSplitQuery2 s: redirect_uri, stringList: [http://localhost/Callback]
```

Answer (score 0):

As part of my task, it was necessary to parse the encoded parameters into a Map<String, Object>
so that single occurrences could be a string, and multiple ones a list.

Requirements:

- Java 8 version
- org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils

Code:

```
var params = "orderNumber=111&orderNumber=222&orderNumber=333&amount=100&returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.local%2Fe9f50435&description=payment&jsonParams=%7B%22emails%22%3A%5B%22test%40test.local%22%5D%2C%22headerId%22%3A%5B%226669666%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%5B%22123123%22%5D%7D&clientId=clientId";

LinkedHashMap<String, Object> collect = URLEncodedUtils.parse(params, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    .stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(
        NameValuePair::getName,
        LinkedHashMap::new,
        collectingAndThen(toList(), list -> {
            if (1 == list.size()) {
                return list.get(0).getValue();
            }

            return list.stream()
                    .map(NameValuePair::getValue)
                    .collect(toList());
        })));
```

Returns this Map:

```
{
    orderNumber=[111, 222, 333],
    amount=100,
    returnUrl=https://test.local/e9f50435,
    description=payment,
    jsonParams={"emails":["test@test.local"],"headerId":["6669666"],"id":["123123"]},
    clientId=clientId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Dmitry Senkovich was the best so far. But what if you want to get the query parameter map from an HttpServletRequest, not from a full URL string? if you do `request.getRequestURL()` you get everything except the query string. If you do `request.getQueryString()` you get just the query string. You could concatenate those and then use the method suggested.

However, here's a one-liner (almost) that will return a nice `MultiValueMap` from a `HttpServletRequest`, *without* using `getQueryParams()` (which makes `getInputStream()` fail):

```
    final MultiValueMap<String,String> m = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().
         query(request.getQueryString()).build().getQueryParams();
```

You're creating an "empty" `UriComponentBuilder`, then setting the query string, then getting it back as a `MultiValueMap`.

Answer (score -1):

## org.keycloak.common.util.UriUtils

I had to parse URIs and Query Parameters in a Keycloak extension and found this utility classes very useful:

```
org.keycloak.common.util.UriUtils:
static MultivaluedHashMap<String,String> decodeQueryString(String queryString)
```

There is also a useful method to delete one query parameter:

```
static String   stripQueryParam(String url, String name)
```

And to parse the URL there is
org.keycloak.common.util.KeycloakUriBuilder:

```
KeycloakUriBuilder  uri(String uriTemplate)
String  getQuery()
```

and lots of other goodies.