# java print the redirected url

Tags: java, url, redirect

original url : `http://pricecheckindia.com/go/store/ebay/52440?ref=velusliv`

redirected url : `http://www.ebay.in/itm/Asus-Zenfone-6-A600CG-A601CG-White-16-GB-/111471688863?pt=IN_Mobile_Phones&aff_source=DA`

I need a program that will take the `original url` and print the `redirected url`.

How to get this done in java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    String url = "http://pricecheckindia.com/go/store/ebay/52440?ref=velusliv";
    Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).followRedirects(false).execute();
    System.out.println(response.url());
}
```

Comment: tried something in jsoup... but not getting it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are being redirected via JavaScript code, which Jsoup doesn't support (it is simple HTML parser, not browser emulator). Your choice then is to either use tool which will support JavaScript  like Selenium web driver, or parse your page to get url from `click here` link from

> If it is taking too long to redirect, then please `click here`

text.

You can use Jsoup to get this link by adding to your current code

```
Document doc = response.parse();
String redirectUrl = doc.select("a:contains(click here)").attr("href");
System.out.println(redirectUrl);
```

which will return and print

> `http://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/4686-127726-2357-15/2?&site=Partnership_PRCCHK&aff_source=DA&mpre=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.in%2Fitm%2FAsus-Zenfone-6-A600CG-A601CG-White-16-GB-%2F111471688863%3Fpt%3DIN_Mobile_Phones%26aff_source%3DDA`

so now all we need to do is parse query from this URL to get value of `mpre` key, which encoded version looks like

> `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.in%2Fitm%2FAsus-Zenfone-6-A600CG-A601CG-White-16-GB-%2F111471688863%3Fpt%3DIN_Mobile_Phones%26aff_source%3DDA`

but after decoding it will actually represents

> `http://www.ebay.in/itm/Asus-Zenfone-6-A600CG-A601CG-White-16-GB-/111471688863?pt=IN_Mobile_Phones&aff_source=DA`

To get value of this key and decode it you can use one of solutions from this question: [Parse a URI String into Name-Value Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-the-uri-string-into-name-value-collection-in-java). With help of method from accepted answer in previously mentioned question we can just invoke

```
URL address = new URL(redirectUrl);
Map<String,List<String>> urlQuerryMap= splitQuery(address);
String redirected = urlQuerryMap.get("mpre").get(0); 
System.out.println(redirected);
```

to see result

> `http://www.ebay.in/itm/Asus-Zenfone-6-A600CG-A601CG-White-16-GB-/111471688863?pt=IN_Mobile_Phones&aff_source=DA`