# Regex to parse a command string

Tags: java, regex, parsing

What is the regex to parse a `String` into a `java.util.Map` where the String have a defined format like this:

```
message_type={any_text}&message_number={digits}&code={digits}&id={digits}&message={any_text}&timestamp={digits_with_decimal}
```

The goal is to generate a Map with message_type, message_number, code, id, message and timestamp keys.

Is this something that a regex can parse? Or this would need a parser with grammar?

**Update:**

This is not the same URI parsing problem. The message here is a body String thus may include '&' in the message part. Using the same split with '&' might cause a wrong split.

Also, the `{ }` are just the ideal function that needs to be replaced by the regex.

Comment: Can't you use a standard library for parsing query strings?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-the-uri-string-into-name-value-collection-in-java

Comment: My concern with splitting is that its possible that the message part may contain the character '&' causing it to split there also which is not a desired output

Comment: You should probably write more about data you want to parse. Can there be line breaks? Can input contain more than one `message_type` element?

Comment: The format is defined and there is no duplicate key

Comment: Are you assuming that data will be always in good format or do you want to test if `message_number={digits}` really contains only digits?

Comment: `String[] parts = command.substring(0, command.length() - 1).split("}&");` Then split parts using `"={"`.

Comment: @Bubletan As stated earlier `&` can be part of data, also something tells me that `{` and `}` are not required and they exist in `{any_text}` just to describe expected data-type.

Comment: Have you tried using [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key is to use lazy evaluation and the following should do the trick:

```
([a-zA-Z].*?={.*?})
```

Start with a letter (lower or upper) till the first occurrence of "=" and then get the value including the braces and repeat.

Demo:
https://regex101.com/r/iE0hU3/1

Comment: However there is no actual curly braces in the message, that was just the idea