# How to extract the value of ID1 and ID2 in a string

Tags: java

I have a string test in which I can see VD1 and and VD2.
How can I extract the value of VD1 and VD2 and store it in string.

```
String test =
  "DomainName=xyz.zzz.com
   &ModifiedOn=03%2f17%2f2015
   &VD1=MTMwMDE3MDQ%3d
   &VD2=B67E48F6969E99A0BC2BEE0E240D2B5C
   &SiteLanguage=English"
```

Here value of `VD1=MTMwMDE3MDQ%3d` and `VD2=B67E48F6969E99A0BC2BEE0E240D2B5C`. But these are the dynamic values. Here VD1 and VD2 are seperated by '&'.

Comment: Looks like it is URL encoded, is it from an URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-the-uri-string-into-name-value-collection-in-java/13592324#13592324](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-the-uri-string-into-name-value-collection-in-java/13592324#13592324)

Answer (score 1):

Try regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String test = "DomainName=xyz.zzz.com&ModifiedOn=03%2f17%2f2015&VD1=MTMwMDE3MDQ%3d&VD2=B67E48F6969E99A0BC2BEE0E240D2B5C&SiteLanguage=English";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("VD1=(.*)&VD2=(.*)&");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }

}
```

O/P :

```
MTMwMDE3MDQ%3d
B67E48F6969E99A0BC2BEE0E240D2B5C
```

Comment: That will break if VD2 appears before VD1

Comment: @neuhaus - who told you that it will?.

Comment: The regexp as present requires VD1 to be directly followed by VD2 to work properly

Comment: @neuhaus - Agreed. I can make it *unnecessarily complicated* by making VD1 and VD2 *independent*. If the OP requests such a thing, then i will change my regex. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions or use the String index() and split() methods.

A regular expression that matches and captures the VD1 value is

```
/VD1=([^&]*)/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that theres always a "&" behind the values of VD1 and VD2, this kind of splitting will do:

```
    String test = "DomainName=xyz.zzz.com&ModifiedOn=03%2f17%2f2015&VD1=MTMwMDE3MDQ%3d&VD2=B67E48F6969E99A0BC2BEE0E240D2B5C&SiteLanguage=English";
    String vd1 = test.substring(test.indexOf("VD1=")+4, test.indexOf("&", test.indexOf("VD1")));
    String vd2 = test.substring(test.indexOf("VD2=")+4, test.indexOf("&", test.indexOf("VD2")));

    System.out.println("VD1:" + vd1 + "\nVD2:" + vd2);
```

This is only a demo, for production you'd have to extract the indexes for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.split(...)` to split a String in pieces. For example, `test.split("&")` first splits the String in individual tokens (of the form `"key=value"`).

You could do the following to achieve this:

```
String vd1 = null, vd2 = null;
for (String token : test.split("&")) {
    // For each token, we check if it is one of the keys we need:
    if (token.startsWith("VD1=")) {
        // The number 4 represents the length of the String "vd1="
        vd1 = token.substring(4);
    } else if (token.startsWith("VD2=") {
        vd2 = token.substring(4);
    }
}
System.out.println("VD1 = " + vd1);
System.out.println("VD2 = " + vd2);
```

However, if you want to parse arbitrary keys, consider using a more robust solution (instead of hard-coding the keys in the for-loop).

Also see [the documentation for the String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 0):

```
String test = "DomainName=xyz.zzz.com&Test&ModifiedOn=03%2f17%2f2015&VD1=MTMwMDE3MDQ%3d&VD2=B67E48F6969E99A0BC2BEE0E240D2B5C&SiteLanguage=English";
HashMap<String, String> paramsMap  = new HashMap<String, String>();
String[] params = test.split("&");
for (int i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
    String[] param = params[i].split("=");
    String paramName = URLDecoder.decode(param[0], "UTF-8");
    String paramValue = null;
    if(param.length > 1)
        paramValue = URLDecoder.decode(param[1], "UTF-8");

    paramsMap.put(paramName, paramValue);
}
String vd1 = paramsMap.get("VD1");
String vd2 = paramsMap.get("VD2");
```