# How to get value of specific parameter in URL - Selenium web driver

Tags: selenium

I have URL - https://www.google.co.in/?token=EC-64B45293U3660525V&PayerID=6JQLFHSWTERMY

From above URL, i want to take value of PayerID field in selenium web driver. please assist on this

Comment: why would you need selenium web driver and not just parse the url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse the Uri string into name-value collection in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-the-uri-string-into-name-value-collection-in-java)