# Regex parse content of HTTP request

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match these kind of character sequences:

```
sender=11&receiver=2&subject=3&message=4
sender=AOFJOIA&receiver=p2308u48302rf0&subject=(@#UROJ)(J#OFN:&message=aoefhoa348!!!
```

Where the delimiters between (key, val) pair is the '&' character.
I'd like to group them in a way I can get access to the key and the value of each pair.

I tried something like:

```
([[:alnum:]]+)=([[:alnum:]]+)
```

But then I miss the:

```
subject=(@#UROJ)(J#OFN:
```

I couldn't find a way to allow these type of characters to be accepted.
To be more specific, if there are `n` pairs of key-value, I would like to have `n` matches, each consisting of 2 groups - 1 for the key, 1 for the value.

I'd be glad if you helped me out with this.

Thanks

Comment: Why? Wouldn't it be easier to use a request parser? Not saying you don't have a legitimate need to do this, but... it's pretty rare.

Comment: subject=(@#UROJ)(J#OFN: are basically special characters which `alnum` doesn't cover

Comment: RegEx cant parse html properly

Comment: Lets say I cannot use any parser but have to implement one.
What would you do instead of using regex?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-the-uri-string-into-name-value-collection-in-java

Comment: Instead of trying to find an elaborate regex, why not do it in a few simple steps?  Like `split("&")`, then `split("=", 2)`.  You can even do it on one line, as of Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

https://regex101.com/r/hN7qG9/1

I guess that will solve your problem:

> /([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?/ig

**output:**

> sender=11 
>   receiver=2 
>   subject=3 
>   message=4 
>   sender=AOFJOIA 
>   receiver=p2308u48302rf0
>   subject=(@#UROJ)(J#OFN:
>   message=aoefhoa348!!!

and you can acess each patter:

```
 $1 - first pattern (sender)
 $2 - second pattern (=11)
 $3 - second pattern without '='(11)
```

[reference](http://stevenbenner.com/2010/03/javascript-regex-trick-parse-a-query-string-into-an-object/)

```js
var string = 'sender=11&receiver=2&subject=3&message=4'
var string2 = 'sender=AOFJOIA&receiver=p2308u48302rf0&subject=(@#UROJ)(J#OFN:&message=aoefhoa348!!!';

var regex = /([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?/ig;
var eachMatche = string.match(regex);

for (var i = 0; i < eachMatche.length; i++) {
  snippet.log(eachMatche[i]);
  snippet.log('First : '+eachMatche[i].replace(regex,'$1'));
  snippet.log('Second : '+eachMatche[i].replace(regex,'$3'));
}
var eachMatche = string2.match(regex);
for (var i = 0; i < eachMatche.length; i++) {
  snippet.log(eachMatche[i]);
  snippet.log('First : '+eachMatche[i].replace(regex,'$1'));
  snippet.log('Second : '+eachMatche[i].replace(regex,'$3'));
}
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the special characters in your example fall unter the "punctuation" group, see :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

If that still isn't enough, you could try to make your own character regex class. Like [@# etc...] . Keep in mind that you will have to escape special java characters with an extra  /.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String req = "sender=AOFJOIA&receiver=p2308u48302rf0&subject=(@#UROJ)(J#OFN:&message=aoefhoa348!!!";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\w]+)=([^&]+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(req);

    while (m.find()){
        System.out.println("key = " + m.group(1)); // key
        System.out.println("value = " + m.group(2)); // value
    }
```

You should define your own character class for the "value" group of key/value pair.
For instance, it could be `` [\w!"#$%'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~] ``
or `[\w@()#:!]` or just as simple as the following: `[^&]`.
I think `[^&]` character class is the most appropriate since you don't know all possible characters that can be in "value" part.