# How to parse a uri with parameters into a Map in Java

Tags: java, parsing, dictionary

I want to parse the following:

```
full_uri= "path/for/uri?$param1=value1&$param2=value2
```

in a way that gives me the uri as a string and the parameters as a map.  What I'm trying right now is:

```
String[] full_uri_split = full_uri.split("\\?");
String uri = full_uri_split[0];
String parameters = full_uri_split[1];
```

This gives me 2 variables, 1 that is the uri, and another that is a string containing all the parameters, in the format of:

```
parameters = "$param1=value1&$param2=value2"
```

My next best guess is to then split it on the & signs:

```
String parameters_split = parameters.split("&");
```

which returns:

```
["$param1=value1", "$param2=value2"]
```

Now I want to convert this into a Map that looks like so:

```
"param1":"value1",
"param2":"value2"
```

and I'm not sure how to go about it.

I'm sure I could get it to work by doing more splits, but it seems horribly inefficient.  So essentially, I want to turn:

```
full_uri = "path/for/uri?$param1=value1&$param2=value2"
```

into

```
uri = "path/for/uri"
params = {
    "param1": "value1",
    "param2": "value2"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse the Uri string into name-value collection in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-the-uri-string-into-name-value-collection-in-java)

Comment: Parameter names can be duplicated in URI. "path/for/uri?p=1&p=2" is a valid URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using a loop.

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
for (String s : parameters_split){
    params.put(s.split("=")[0], s.split("=")[1]);
}
```