# Parse a string with key=value pair in a map?

Tags: java, string, split, guava, splitter

I have below String which is in the format of `key1=value1, key2=value2` which I need to load it in a map `(Map<String, String>)` as `key=value` so I need to split on comma `,` and then load `cossn` as key and `0` its value.

```
String payload = "cossn=0, itwrqm=200006033213";
Map<String, String> holder =
          Splitter.on(",").trimResults().withKeyValueSeparator("=").split(payload);
```

I am using Splitter here to do the job for me but for some cases it is failing. For some of my strings, value has some string with equal sign. So for below string it was failing for me:

```
String payload = "cossn=0, abc=hello/=world";
```

How can I make it work for above case? For above case `key` will be `abc` and value should be `hello/=world`. Is this possible to do?

Comment: how can you make what work exactly?  Splitter?  Java?  There's a bunch of different ways to do this, but maybe no one line function strings.

Comment: adding 2 to the split call should work.

Comment: After adding 2 to the split, I see this error `The method split(CharSequence) in the type Splitter.MapSplitter is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)`.

Comment: @user1950349: littlecegian was referring to `String.split`, which you aren't using (but which Tomer's answer below uses). `MapSplitter.split` doesn't have any overload that takes a number of splits, but you can use the `limit()` API on `Splitter` to get the same effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can add a number to say how many splits you want just add a 2 to split

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        HashMap<String, String> holder = new HashMap();
        String payload = "cossn=0, abc=hello/=world";
        String[] keyVals = payload.split(", ");
        for(String keyVal:keyVals)
        {
          String[] parts = keyVal.split("=",2);
          holder.put(parts[0],parts[1]);
        }

     }
}
```

Comment: This is the error I am seeing `The method split(CharSequence) in the type Splitter.MapSplitter is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)`.

Comment: have you considered using a loop instead?

Comment: Can you provide an example how can I do that?

Comment: @user1950349 see my edit

Comment: I just tried this, and it gave `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on this line `holder.put(parts[0], parts[1]);`. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: i think i i may have messed up the quotes try now. it works for me

Comment: I would recommend using a `Splitter` rather than `String.split()` like you have here, for all the reasons called out in the Splitter documentation: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#splitter

Comment: Will not work in case you have a `, ` in your text

Comment: @GuyT Yes thats correct. But it depends how you are getting your data fed to you. Any good comma separated list would support escaping commas in the text, either by putting quotes around the text which contains a comma, or by putting a backslash or some escaping character before a comma, which you could then implement some logic to decode the escaped commas. If the data you are being fed does not escape commas within the text, it will be extremely difficult to split it correctly, but there may be some ways using other regex type logic.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this same thing with the `Splitter` API directly:

```
Map<String, String> result = Splitter.on(',')
    .trimResults()
    .withKeyValueSeparator(
        Splitter.on('=')
            .limit(2)
            .trimResults())
    .split(input);
```