# Parse a string with delimiters and load it in a map?

Tags: java, regex, string, split, guava

I have below String which is in the format of `key1=value1, key2=value2` which I need to load it in a map `(Map<String, String>)` as `key=value` so I need to split on comma `,` and then load `cossn` as key and `0` its value.

```
String payload = "cossn=0, abc=hello/=world, Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36";

HashMap<String, String> holder = new HashMap();
String[] keyVals = payload.split(", ");
for(String keyVal:keyVals) {
  String[] parts = keyVal.split("=",2);
  holder.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
}
```

I am getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at this line `holder.put(parts[0], parts[1]);` and it is happening bcoz of this String `Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36` since it has an extra comma in the value `KHTML, like Gecko`.

How can I fix this? In general below should be my keys and value after loading it in a map.

```
Key         Value
cossn       0
abc         hello/=world
Agent       Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Will there always be 4 commas ?

Comment: No this is just a sample string. In general it is a very long string and content will change most of the time.

Comment: Can you define the format of the input or is this fixed?

Comment: This is fixed, I don't have any control on this at all.

Comment: You're going to have to do some fancy parsing to only get commas immediately preceding equals signs.    What control do you have over the input string/payload?  Seems you need to wrap that better than a comma-delimited string like you have.  I'd suggest using JSON which is designed for things like this.

Comment: I don't have any control on this payload at all.

Comment: Where is the payload coming from?  Who is providing it to you and by what means?

Comment: Will the keys only contain alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Yes keys will only have alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @DanielWiddis Let's not worry about from where the payload is coming from. Sometimes there are things that you cannot change.

Comment: If you are stuck with the payload format, you will never get this properly done. You will always have to use some heuristics to decide where to split and where not if you cannot quote the keys and values or escape the delimiters if they are not delimiters. How would you e. g. split `a=a, b=b, c,c=d`? Is `b` = `b, c` or is `c,c = d`? However you decide, it will be a heuristic that will probably fail with some input.

Comment: In your above case this is true `b = b, c` not the other one.

Comment: Yeah, but that is arbitrary heuristic you chose. Now you have to formulate your heuristics you would do manually into some code. Given the keys are only alphanumeric I gave you a suggestion as answer.

Comment: @frenchDolphin you should read what I write before you make non-matching comments

Comment: @user1950349: This looks exactly the same as your question "[Parse a string with key=value pair in a map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401889/parse-a-string-with-key-value-pair-in-a-map)". Please don't post the same question multiple times.

Comment: It is different than previous one.. Question is almost same.. In that one, I was having issues with `=` which got fixed but then I ran into this `,` issue so that's why I opened a new one.

Comment: See also [Parse a URI String into Name-Value Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said your keys only contain alphanumerics, the following would probably be a good heuristic for splitting:

```
payload.split("\\s*,\\s*(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\s*=|$)");
```

Which will split on probably whitespace framed commas that are followed by the end of the string or an alphanumeric key, optional whitespace and an equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have no control over the payload, you need to do something to make the "illegal commas" not match your ", " regex.

Vampire provided a great regex.   Since I've already gone down the road of manual parsing, I'll provide a non-regex solution below.

An alternate solution is to manually find the parse/split points yourself by iterating character by character and saving substrings. Keep track of the "last comma-space" until you get to the "next equals" in order to determine whether to split on that comma-space or not.

Here's some code that demonstrates what I'm trying to explain.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ParseTest {

    static String payload = "cossn=0, abc=hello/=world, Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int lastCommaSpace = -2;
        int beginIndex = 0;

        // Iterate over string
        // We are looking for comma-space pairs so we stop one short of end of
        // string
        for (int i = 0; i < payload.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (payload.charAt(i) == ',' && payload.charAt(i + 1) == ' ') {
                // This is the point we want to split at
                lastCommaSpace = i;
            }
            if (payload.charAt(i) == '=' && lastCommaSpace != beginIndex - 2) {
                // We've found the next equals, split at the last comma we saw
                String pairToSplit = payload.substring(beginIndex, lastCommaSpace);
                System.out.println("Split and add this pair:" + Arrays.toString(pairToSplit.split("=", 2)));
                beginIndex = lastCommaSpace + 2;
            }
        }
        // We got to the end, split the last one
        String pairToSplit = payload.substring(beginIndex, payload.length());
        System.out.println("Split and add this pair:" + Arrays.toString(pairToSplit.split("=", 2)));
    }

}
```