# Split the dynamic String in java

Tags: java

I have a string as follows and I'm splitting the parameters (TransactionType, ServiceID, PaymentID, OrderNumber, Amount) as below.

```
String response = "TransactionType=SALE&ServiceID=TV3&PaymentID=PYID2016061501417701&OrderNumber=2016061501417701&Amount=235.00"

String splitParams[] = res.split("&");
        String TransactionType = splitParams[0].substring(splitParams[0]
                .indexOf("=") + 1);
        String ServiceID = splitParams[1].substring(splitParams[1]
                .indexOf("=") + 1);
        String PaymentID = splitParams[2].substring(splitParams[2]
                .indexOf("=") + 1);
        String OrderNumber = splitParams[3].substring(splitParams[3]
                .indexOf("=") + 1);
        String amount = splitParams[4].substring(splitParams[4]
                .indexOf("=") + 1);
```

But the problem is these parameters are not sent in order and sometimes some parameters are not sent. Is there any way to split the parameters in string using java based on parameter name?

Comment: Why don't you create a `Map` instead?

Comment: As I understand, you have an URL fragment. I think you could find plenty of answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection , most of them deal with url, but it should fit also to only parameter part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use guavas Splitter like this:

```
Map<String, String> responseMap = Splitter.on("&")
        .omitEmptyStrings()
        .trimResults()
        .withKeyValueSeparator("=")
        .split(response);
```

And then you could get the values like that:

```
String TransactionType = responseMp.get("TransactionType ");
```

Comment: I'm getting error "The method withKeyValueSeparator(String) is undefined for the type Splitter". I have added "com.google.guava_1.6.0.jar". Can u please help with that?

Comment: @dmaprasad this function  is only from Google Guava, if you want to use it you need to import it like import com.google.common.base.Splitter;

Comment: I have imported like com.google.common.base.Splitter;. But same result. not working. do u have any idea. Really appreciate help

Comment: I use guava-18.0.jar. The maven-dependency is 
     `<dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
         <artifactId>guava</artifactId><version>18.0</version>
      </dependency>`

Comment: Thank you very much. By replacing guava-18.0.jar with com.google.guava_1.6.0.jar is worked. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String response = "TransactionType=SALE&ServiceID=TV3&PaymentID=PYID2016061501417701&OrderNumber=2016061501417701&Amount=235.00";

Map<String,String> responseMap = Arrays.asList(response.split("&")).stream().
     map(v-> v.split("=")).collect(Collectors.toMap(a-> a[0],a ->a[1]));



System.out.println(responseMap);
```

output:

> {TransactionType=SALE, Amount=235.00, PaymentID=PYID2016061501417701, OrderNumber=2016061501417701, ServiceID=TV3}

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Above answer really matched with my requirement.