# How to substitute a query parameter in a string url

Tags: java, string, url

Hello I have a url string like

```
http://example.com/foo/?bar=15&oof=myp
```

Now lets say that I want to change the int value in the bar parameter to 16, in order to have

```
http://example.com/foo/?bar=16&oof=myp
```

How can I do this? Considering that the number after the = might be of 1, 2 or ever 3 characters. Thank you

Comment: have look into this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use UriComponentsBuilder (it's part of [Spring Web jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web)) like this:

```
String url = "http://example.com/foo/?bar=15&oof=myp";

UriComponentsBuilder urlBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url);

urlBuilder.replaceQueryParam("bar", 107);

String result = urlBuilder.build().toUriString();
```

Substitute 107 with the number you want. With this method you can have URI or String object from urlBuilder.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks much.

Comment: Please mention where UriComponentBuilder is sourced from (believe this is from Spring)

Comment: @Mahesh updated the answer, and yes it's part of spring web jar.

Answer (score -3):

1. Use regex to find the number parameter in the string url
2. Use `String.replace()` to replace the old parameter with the new parameter

Comment: I don't know how to use regex

Comment: Mention a working example code as to solve the above issue.