# How to parse a zillow URL in java

Tags: java, parsing, url, zillow

I need to get the "zpid" from the URL for example see the following link:
http://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/Laie-HI/110560800_zpid/18901_rid/pricea_sort/21.70624,-157.843323,21.565342,-158.027859_rect/12_zm/

I need to get the value 110560800

I found URL Parser https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html
but I could not find a way to get the "zpid"

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection

Something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a regular expression to match the group you want. In your case `zpid` is a number to match a number `\d+` to be used

```
private static String extract(String url) { // http://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/Laie-HI/110560800_zpid/18901_rid/pricea_sort/21.70624,-157.843323,21.565342,-158.027859_rect/12_zm/
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)_zpid");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.group(1); //110560800
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can cast this `String` to number by using `Integer.parseInt`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do:

```
String s = "http://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/Laie-HI/110560800_zpid/18901_rid/pricea_sort/21.70624,-157.843323,21.565342,-158.027859_rect/12_zm/";

        String[] url = s.split("/");//separating the string with delimeter "/" in url

        for(int i=0;i<url.length;i++){
            if(url[i].contains("zpid")){//go through each slit strings and search for keyword zpid
                String[] zpid = url[i].split("_");//if zpid is found, get the number part
                System.out.println(zpid[0]);

            }
        }
```

Comment: While this may work for the given URL, it is not very fault tolerant. It is better practice to use a regular expression to parse the data out of the URL. @Saravana provides a good example of this.

Comment: @ZacharyDavidSaunders agreed