# How to remove all characters before a specific character in Java?

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a string and I'm getting value through a html form so when I get the value it comes in a URL so I want to remove all the characters before the specific charater which is `=` and I also want to remove this character. I only want to save the value that comes after `=` because I need to fetch that value from the variable..

**EDIT : I need to remove the `=` too since I'm trying to get the characters/value in string after it...**

Comment: @ItamarGreen I don't know how to do it since I'm a beginner so I searched it up on the internet and I didn't find anything that I could understand so please if you know help me understand it

Comment: did you search google for exactly your title?

Comment: what about `split()` and only use the 2nd value?

Comment: @ItamarGreen Yes but the explanations are very poor

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, then, `split(url,2)`, just in case

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I don't know what that is, sorry.

Comment: @AxelH I don't know how to use split lol

Comment: Well, you didn't tried anything then ... Please do some research.

Comment: @AxelH I actually did but it gives me nullpointerexception, if u stop commenting and let me try the answers lol i would be really thankful ill get back to you in a moment

Comment: @AxelH still gives back an array, therefore it does not make any difference

Comment: @ShariqMusharaf did you manage to get it working?

Comment: What you really want is parse query parameters. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, yes but if you more than one `=` you will split on the first one. You could missed some data if you don't specify this

Comment: @AxelH ahh okay now i see the sense of it.

Comment: @ShariqMusharaf What you **really** want is to do **much** more learning on java basics. It is a rather bad idea to learn "android" and java at the same time. It rather looks like you are completely overburdening yourself at this point in time.

Comment: @GhostCat thx for voting down and I have learned java basics but since I'm doing a revision I have forgot a lot :(

Comment: @ShariqMusharaf did you get it working?

Comment: @ShariqMusharaf for the record:I did not downvote

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use `.substring()`:

```
String s = "the text=text";
String s1 = s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 1);
s1.trim();
```

then `s1` contains everything after `=` in the original string.

#### **s1.trim()**

`.trim()` removes spaces before the first character (which isn't a whitespace, such as letters, numbers etc.) of a string (leading spaces) and also removes spaces after the last character (trailing spaces).

Comment: If there are multiple `=` you can get the index of the last occurrence with `s.lastIndexOf("=")`.

Comment: Just to add, if anyone wants to get the text before =, you can use this: String s1 = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("=")); then s1 contains everything before = in the original string.

Answer (score 9):

While there are many answers. Here is a regex example

```
String test = "eo21jüdjüqw=realString";
test = test.replaceAll(".+=", "");
System.out.println(test);

// prints realString
```

Explanation:

`.+` matches any character (except for line terminators)
`+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
`=` matches the character = literally (case sensitive)

This is also a shady copy paste from https://regex101.com/ where you can try regex out.

Comment: @ShariqMusharaf It's something I randomly chose. The variable `test` is your html String.

Answer (score 6):

You can split the string from the = and separate in to array and take the second value of the array which you specify as after the = sign
For example:

`String CurrentString = "Fruit = they taste good";
String[] separated = CurrentString.split("=");
separated[0]; // this will contain "Fruit"
separated[1]; //this will contain "they teste good"`

then separated[1] contains everything after = in the original string.

Comment: I need to remove the "=" too

Comment: yes it will remove that  "=" and store it in separated[1] that you exactly want.

Comment: Not everything ! Try this `Op = 4 = 2 + 2`

Answer (score 3):

I know this is asked about `Java` but this seems to also be the first search result for `Kotlin` so you should know that `Kotlin` has the `String.substringAfter(delimiter: String, missingDelimiterValue: String = this)` extension for this case.

Its implementation is:

```
val index = indexOf(delimiter)
return if (index == -1) 
    missingDelimiterValue 
else 
    substring(index + delimiter.length, length)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [Apache Commons Lang3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/package-summary.html) library, you can also use the `substringAfter` method of the `StringUtils` utility class.

Official documentation is [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringAfter-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Examples:

```
String value = StringUtils.substringAfter("key=value", "=");   

// in this case where a space is in the value (e.g. read from a file instead of a query params)
String value = StringUtils.trimToEmpty(StringUtils.substringAfter("key = value", "="));   // = "value"
```

It manage the case where your values can contains the '=' character as it takes the first occurence.

If you have keys and values also containing '=' character it will not work (but the other methods as well); in the URL query params, such a character should be escaped anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe locate the first occurrence of the character in the URL String. For Example:

```
String URL = "http://test.net/demo_form.asp?name1=stringTest";

int index = URL.indexOf("=");
```

Then, split the String based on an index

```
String Result = URL.substring(index+1); //index+1 to skip =
```

String Result now contains the value: stringTest

Comment: @sha If you don't want to include the "=", simply increment the index by 1.