# I can only get part of a url and put into string in android?

Tags: android, string, url

Ok I wasn't really sure how to word this question, but basically what I want to do is, I got a url from a RSS feed in android, and I need to put part of that url into a string, the url will look something like this: `http://www.prsn.uprm.edu/Spanish/Informe_Sismo/myinfoGeneral.php?id=20161206012821`and I only want the part after id=, ONLY the number, is that possible? Please help me, Thanks

Comment: Check out the answers provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection) on how to parse a URI string

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using two ways:

```
    // One Way
    String url = "http://www.prsn.uprm.edu/Spanish/Informe_Sismo/myinfoGeneral.php?id=20161206012821";
    String substr = "=";
    String after = url.substring(url.indexOf(substr) + substr.length());

    // Second Way

    String[] parts = url.split(substr);
    String afterTwo = parts[1];
```

Comment: Hi, I need to load the _after_ in this url`"http://shake.uprm.edu/~shake/archive/shake/"here"/download/tvmap.jpg"` how i can do this?

Comment: I need to load into Glide 'Glide.with(context).load(here).into(holder.Thumbnail);'