# How to get values from string in java?

Tags: java, string

My string: `result = order=7781&state=1&value=&add=114GH;`

I want to get values:

```
String order = "7781";
String state = "1";
String value = "";
String add = "114GH";
```

Please help me to solve this problem! Thanks!

I have done till here, but its not working.

```
String[] resDetails = result.split("&");
for(String pair : resDetails)                       
        {
            String[] entry = pair.split("=");                    
            map.put(entry[0].trim(), entry[1].trim());        
        }
```

Its giving error because `value` is empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse a URI String into Name-Value Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13592236/5221149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change [`split("=")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) to [`split("=", -1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-), so trailing empty strings will not be discarded.

Comment: This is working, please can you explain what it does actually? split("=", -1)

Comment: Click on it and read the javadoc. It's why I added the links.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help!