# Regex Multiple Different Values in one string

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching

I need to enumerate through a string finding all the [ ] and getting the text in between and replacing it all with something different.

For example:

http:\www.domain.com\id=[USER_ID]&record=[CALL_KEY]&someother=[OTHER_STUFF]

As it stands now I have to hard code each individual key and replace it with the value.

```
private String injectValues(String url) {

    String injected = url.replace("[CALL_KEY]", "123");
    injected = injected.replace("[USER_ID]", "some user ide");
    injected = injected.replace("[OTHER_STUFF]", "somethingElse");

    return injected;

}
```

I have a bunch of different values that can be plugged in, and instead of hard coding [CALL KEY] etc, I would like to dynamically read what is in there and inject the value.

I have used a RegEx `enumerateMatchesInString` in Objective-C, is there an Android/Java equivalent?

I have tinkered with `Pattern` but I don't' know enough about it to make it work for what I want.

```
private void injectValues(String url) {

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[(.+?)]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);

....///EEEEEHH  how do I get the matches?
         String key = ;//THE VALUE INSIDE THE SQUARE BRACKETS
         String aValue = someMethodToGetTheValueForKey(key);

}

 private String someMethodToGetTheValueForKey(String key){
        return "Something";
    }
```

Comment: there are already a multitude of questions about parsing querystring

Comment: Oh great, did you care to give some URLs to questions that relate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse a URI String into Name-Value Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection)

Comment: That doesn't really fit, since that solution is breaking at `&`. My string may have `&` but no `[TEXT]`. I am looking for a way to take a string and find `[TEXT]` and replace it with something else. Any string. It doesn't have to be a URL. I was using that as an example.

Comment: Can't you just maintain a dictionary of key value pairs and do the replacements in a loop?

String injected = url;

for(String key : properties.keySet()) 
{
 injected = injected.replace("[" + key + "]", properties.get(key);
}

I don't see the need for a generic regex since you can only replace the values for known keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are missing:

```
// how do I get the matches?
while(matcher.find()) {
     String key = matcher.group(1); //THE VALUE INSIDE THE SQUARE BRACKETS
```

Also, you may want to take a look at the example code in the documentation of [Matcher.appendReplacement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) and use it as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a very simple aproach.

If you could use ***Apache commons***, yo could do:

```
String s = "id=[USER_ID]&record=[CALL_KEY]&someother=[OTHER_STUFF]";
String[] arrayKeys = StringUtils.substringsBetween(s, "[", "]")
```

The ***arrayKeys*** will contains the keys between " [ ] ". Then you should replace ***"["+arrayKeys[0]+"]***" for your value for example.

Comment: I can't use Apache Commons. This would have been great though