# How to find optional group with some prefix using Regex

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, string-matching

This is my pattern regex:

```
"subcategory.html?.*id=(.*?)&.*title=(.+)?"
```

for below input

`http://example.com/xyz/subcategory.html?id=3000080292&backTitle=Back&title=BabySale`
I want to capturebelow group

- group one (id) : 3000080292
- group two (title) : BabySale

For which it is working fine. The problem is I want to make second group i.e. value of title to be optional, so that even if title is not present, regex should match and get me value of group 1(id). But for input

```
http://example.com/xyz/subcategory.html?id=3000080292&backTitle=Back&
```

Regex match is failing even if group one is present. So my question is how to make second group optional here?

Comment: I'm sorry but if your use-case is retricted to parsing URLs, maybe you should see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection or even use one of the many libraries doing the exact same thing. Regex tends to be vulnerable when doing that kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe make the entire substring optional?

Try `subcategory.html?.*id=(.*?)&.*(?:title=(.+)?)?`

Also note that your (and my) regex might be matching too much. For example, the dot here should probably be escaped: `subcategory\.html` instead of `subcategory.html` or you will match `subcategory€html`, too. Your question mark says the `l` of `html` is optional; you are probably saved by the `.*` ("match anything"), that follows.

Last but not least, the final `.*` means that even this will match (which you probably don't want to match):

```
http://example.com/xyz/subcategory.html?id=3000080292&backTitle=Back&title=BabySale&Lorem Ipsum Sit Atem http://&%$
```

It's usually a bad idea to match `.*` as it will nearly always match too much. Consider using character classes instead of the dot, and to anchor he beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string... :)

Comment: but above regex is failing to match http://example.com/xyz/subcategory.html?id=3000080292&backTitle=Back&   for group one

Comment: When I try it, it fails to find anything for group two (title), most likely because the preceding `.*` is too greedy - making it non-greedy should fix the issue - although `backTitle` has a capital `T` and we are only looking for a lowercase one. This might do: `subcategory\.html\?.*id=(.*?)&(?:.*?title=(\w+)?)?` - provided title comes last, and you don't want `backTitle`... See https://regex101.com/r/H9OKlb/3

Comment: NB: You are using Java, so make sure to properly escape the regex pattern!

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible ways is to use something like:

```
subcategory\.html\?.*id=(.*?)&(.*title=(.+)?)?
(.*title=(.+)?)? is optional now.
```

please see an example [here](https://regex101.com/r/S1Znk3/1).

As suggested by @Christian it is better to make `.*title` **non capturing** group and it won't be part of the result.

```
subcategory\.html\?.*id=(.*?)&(?:.*title=(.+)?)?
```

Comment: You may also want to make the group around the `title` bit non-capturing (`(?:)` instead of `()`), to avoid the regex engine saving the result in a variable (thus changing the index numbers of existing ones): `subcategory\.html\?.*id=(.*?)&(?:.*title=(.+)?)?`

Comment: but above regex is failing to match "http://example.com/xyz/subcategory.html?id=3000080292&backTitle=Back& " for group one ?

Answer (score 1):

If you know that parameter `id` comes before optional `title` then you can use this regex to capture `id` and optional `title` parameters:

```
subcategory\.html\?id=([^&]*)(?:.*&)?(?:title=([^&]*))?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QxKQUA/2)

In Java use this regex:

```
final String regex = "subcategory\\.html\\?id=([^&]*)(?:.*&)?(?:title=([^&]*))?";
```