# Parsing URI query losing values beyond pound sign

Tags: java, uri

When passing a URI query which contains `#` the function seems to stop iterating the query and returns up to just before the `#`

Example URI: `/test.php?hello=Hello+World ljlksjlkdja(#*!!!!()**!&world=Venus`

Will output: `Hello World ljlksjlkdja(`

Expected Output: `Hello World ljlksjlkdja(#*!!!!()**! from Venus`

I have tried replacing the pound signs with `query.replace("#", "%23")` after `tokens` but the problem persists so I am not sure.

Main function it's based on can be found here: [Parse a URI String into Name-Value Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection?rq=1)

Alternately I noticed the author mentioning this would work on arrays, but it only captures the first result from something like `?hello=Hello+World&world[]=Venus&world[]=Mars&world[]=Eartth` which outputs an array `[world]=>Array([0] => Venus)`

```
private static Map<String, List<String>> splitQuery(String query) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final Map<String, List<String>> query_pairs = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
    String[] tokens = query.split("\\?", 2);
    if (tokens.length == 2) {
        query = tokens[1];
        final String[] pairs = query.split("&");
        for (String pair : pairs) {
            final int idx = pair.indexOf("=");
            final String key = idx > 0 ? URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), "UTF-8") : pair;
            if (!query_pairs.containsKey(key)) {
                query_pairs.put(key, new LinkedList<String>());
            }
            final String value = idx > 0 && pair.length() > idx + 1 ? URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), "UTF-8") : null;
            query_pairs.get(key).add(value);
        }
    }
    return query_pairs;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and the example you provide compiles and runs for me:

```
System.out.print(splitQuery("asdfasdfadsf?hello=Hello+World"));
System.out.print(splitQuery("asdfasdfadsf?hello=Hello%20World"));
# output: {hello=[Hello World]}{hello=[Hello World]}
```

One suggestion would be to use `split()` to find key=value pairs instead of manually splitting based on character indexes.

Even better, I'd consider using a third party library to do this work, as suggested in [Parse a URI String into Name-Value Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13592236/3833383).

---

**Updated to address question updates**

The `#` character in a URL introduces a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). According to [RFC 3986, Section 3.5: Fragment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-24):

> A fragment identifier component is indicated by the presence of number sign ("#") character and terminated by the end of the URI.

Thus, it makes sense that query parameter processing ends when the `#` character has been encountered. In order to accept these kinds of characters in your query parameters, they must be encoded. `#` *is* encoded as `%23`, but this encoding must occur before you actually send the request to the server. Using your example, the following should work as you intend:

```
/test.php?hello=Hello%2BWorld%20ljlksjlkdja(%23*!!!!()**!&world=Venus
```

See also [Which characters make a URL invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1547899/3833383) for a discussion on valid URL characters.

Comment: You are correct. I just found the cause of the issue and remedied it. Thank you for your time. Turns out has nothing to do with Java and was a PHP side issue.

Comment: There is a issue with this code though... rephrasing the question actually.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now that you explained it, and is acting as intended.