# Efficient way to split a string in one pass to produce a key value pair and check corner case if key is empty

Tags: java, string, split

Hi guys i have a string `"key={value}&key2={value2}&key3={value3}"` and have to produce a key-value pair of the string by splitting `&` and `=`. Also i have to watch out for corner cases such that if a key isn't present do not add it to the hash map but if a value is missing the key can be added with an empty value. One way is to first split the string by `&` and finally by `=`. So this can be accomplished but having two passes. But i am attempting to accomplish this in one pass.

First idea: I came up with one pass using the split function using  but it didn't account for corner cases.

```
public Map<String, String> splitString(String s) {
    // String s represents ParamAndMacro
    String[] split = s.split("=|\\&");
    int length = split.length;
    Map<String, String> maps = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i=0; i<length; i+=2){
          maps.put(split[i], split[i+1]);
     } 
    return maps;
}
```

Second Idea:
One pass with certain conditions and using stringbuilder:

```
public Map<String, String> splitString(String s){
 Map<String, String> maps = new HashMap<>();
 int length = s.length();
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 String key = "";
 String value = "";

char prev = ' ';
for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    char a = s.charAt(i);
    if ( a != '=' && a != '&' && prev != a) {
           sb.append(a);        
      }
    //finds a key
    else if( a == '=' && prev != a && prev != '&') {
          key = sb.toString();
          sb = new StringBuilder();
      }
    // finds a value and also ensuring a key is not empty
    else if (a=='&' && prev != a && prev != '=') {
          value = sb.toString();
          sb = new StringBuilder();
          maps.put(key, value);
            }
    // checks corner case to see if a value is empty
    else if (prev=='=' && a == '&') {
          value = "";
          maps.put(key, value);
          sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
   //how to check if a key is missing and skip to other pair

            prev = a;
    }
    return maps;
}
```

My question is my code efficient in terms of splitting and using stringbuilder. Please feel free to improve or give suggestions.

Comment: Should be moved to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you need to do it from scratch? check out [this question answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection)

Comment: @JulioDanielReyes no i don't.

Comment: @JulioDanielReyes the link u shared only deals with url but i am receiving the query parameters as strings.

Comment: @user3497437 you could create a dummy URL object from your string, like this `new URL("http://dummyurl.com/?"+queryParams)` or create your own adapter to that interface.