# Replace a Param in QueryString in Java

Tags: java, string, design-patterns, matcher

lets say I have a url param like `token=1234235asdjaklj231k209a&name=sam&firname=Mahan`
how can I replace the value of the token with new one ?
I've done something similar to this with pattern and matcher before but I don't recall now 
but I know there is a way to do so
Update : the token can contain any letter but &
thanks in advance

Comment: what the output should look like?

Comment: @YCF_L the same string but the value of the token is replaced by the new one like token=1234&name=sam&firname=Mahan  that 1234 is the new token for instance and the token contains anything but &

Comment: I don't think this is a job for regex; there are well tested abstractions for urls in java.

Comment: please explain all the cases you can have so we can help you:

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can consider doing a simple regex replacement, with a few caveats (q.v. below the code snippet).

```
String url = "token=1234235asdjaklj231k209a&name=sam&firname=Mahan";
url = url.replaceFirst("\\btoken=.*?(&|$)", "token=new_value$1");
System.out.println(url);
url = "param1=value&token=1234235asdjaklj231k209a";
url = url.replaceFirst("\\btoken=.*?(&|$)", "token=new_value$1");
System.out.println(url);
```

Edge cases to consider are first that your `token` may be the last parameter in the query string.  To cover this case, we should check for `token=...` ending in *either* an ambersand `&` or the end of the string.  But if we don't use a lookahead, and instead consume that ambersand, we have to also add it back in the replacement.  The other edge case, correctly caught by @DodgyCodeException in his comment below, is that there be *another* query parameter which just happens to *end* in `token`.  To make sure we are really matching our `token` parameter, we can preface it with a word boundary in the regex, i.e. use `\btoken=...` to refer to it.

**Output:**

```
token=new_value&name=sam&firname=Mahan
param1=value&token=new_value
```

Comment: What if the query params were "thisisnotatoken=gotcha&token=1234abcd&..."

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Then we should use a word boundary in this case.  You certainly have a nose for dodgy code :-)

Comment: thanks it worked for my cases and that case mentioned above by @DodgyCodeException is not gonna happen for me , but thanks for mentioning that

Comment: I'm glad it helped in your specific case, but for general use this is flaky -
 e.g. there may be a `&amp;` somewhere which will get mistaken by the above. The best way to tackle it would be to use a well-tested URL params parsing library (such as Apache URLEncodedUtils - not saying it's well-tested as after all Apache is a so named because it's a bit patchy, but it's the only one I could find). Then use that to split into a list of name-value pairs, change the appropriate value, and re-encode into a string.

Answer (score 12):

Spring has a util that handles this need gracefully. Apache httpcomponents does too. Below is a spring example.

```
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;
import java.net.URI;


public class StackOverflow {

  private static class SO46303058 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      final String urlString = "https://subdomain.hostname/path/resource?token=1234235asdjaklj231k209a&name=sam&firname=Mahan";
      final URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(urlString)
          .replaceQueryParam("token", "abc")
          .build().toUri();
      System.out.println(uri);
    }
  }
}
```

Don't be afraid of adding dependencies to your project, it beats reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because I feel that in general most URI/URL stuff should be handled by such libraries and not manually.

Comment: thanks that's great news that I'm using Spring too that this helps a lot and its so clean

Comment: has the side effect of changing the order.

Answer (score -3):

make a viewModel.

```
public class veiwModel(){ String token ; // and get and set for exmample }
```

then use Gson if u have a json text .

```
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   yourViewModel = gson.fronJson(jsonText , viewModel.class);
   System.out.println(yourViewModel.getToken());
```