# Serialized form data in Java

Tags: java, jquery, serialization

I serialize the form and send to java via ajax

```
var basic = $("#basicForm").serialize();
$.post("user.do?action=save_details",{basic:basic},function(data){

});
```

The variable `basic` look like

```
name=Ram&age=23&desc=testdescription&place=kilimanoor....
```

Now in java file I want to take each values(name,age,place etc).

In java I have:

```
String basicdata = rq.getParameter("basic");
```

**How I extract each parameters(name, age etc) from basicdata in java?**

Comment: take a look here [parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection)