# URLEncodedUtils does not parse all get params from the given url

Tags: java, httpclient

I have an url and would like to parse and extract params from it. My implementation is based on the following stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13592324/2496648)

However my url is more complex than the one used in the post above. It looks like this:

```
https://example.com/cdscontent/login?initialURI=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fdashboard%2F%3Fportal%3Dmyportal%26LO%3D4%26contentid%3D10007.786471%26viewmode%3Dcontent%26variant%3D%2Fmyportal%2F
```

As you can see it has the param `initialURI` which is (encoded) url itself and the order of the params in it cannot be changed.

When I run `org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils#parse` it returns

```
[initialURI=https://example.com/dashboard/?portal=myportal, LO=4, contentid=10007.786471, viewmode=content, variant=/myportal/]
```

as you can see it parses every param except `portal`. It is still bound to `https://example.com/dashboard/` In other words I am expecting this:

```
[initialURI=https://example.com/dashboard/, portal=myportal, LO=4, contentid=10007.786471, viewmode=content, variant=/myportal/]
```

Am I doing here something wrong or do you think that URLEncodedUtils#parse cannot handle this case?

Do you have any alternative to suggest?

Thx a lot!

Unit test to try

```
public class UrlParserTest {

  @Test
  public void testParseUrl() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, URISyntaxException {

    String url =
        "https://www.example.com/cdscontent/login?initialURI=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fdashboard%2F%3Fportal%3Dmyportal%26LO%3D4%26contentid%3D10007.786471%26viewmode%3Dcontent%26variant%3D%2Fmyportal%2F";

    String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
    List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(decoded), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(params);
  }

}
```

Comment: I can see `?portal=myportal` just fine, your code works

Comment: yeah but still as a part of `initialURI` unlike `LO`, `contentid` etc.

Comment: I see now, your url `https://www.example.com/` has the query parameter `initialURI` which contains another url and other query parameters. What's the expected behaviour? That all query parameters belong to the url in `initialURI`?

Comment: Thats right and I've updated the question with the expected behavior.

Comment: It is clear that you have to get `initialURI` query param value first by parsing the initial string, secondly parse the `initialURI` value.

Answer (score 0):

### What are we working with

You have the following url (decoded):

```
https://www.example.com/cdscontent/login?initialURI=https://www.example.com/dashboard/?portal=myportal&LO=4&contentid=10007.786471&viewmode=content&variant=/myportal/
```

This url consists of the main url:

```
https://www.example.com/cdscontent/login
```

which has 1 query parameter `initialURI`:

```
https://www.example.com/dashboard/?portal=myportal&LO=4&contentid=10007.786471&viewmode=content&variant=/myportal/
```

This url has multiple query parameters (the ones you're looking for):

```
portal=myportal&LO=4&contentid=10007.786471&viewmode=content&variant=/myportal/
```

### Solution

**Step 1:**

We first must get the url in the query parameter `initialURI`:

```
 List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

// Find first NameValuePair where the name equals initialURI
Optional<NameValuePair> initialURI = params.stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getName().equals("initialURI"))
        .findFirst();

System.out.println(initialURI);
```

This prints:

```
Optional[initialURI=https://www.example.com/dashboard/?portal=myportal&LO=4&contentid=10007.786471&viewmode=content&variant=/myportal/]
```

**Step 2:**

Now we can get the query parameters of this url and print them:

```
List<NameValuePair> initialParams = URLEncodedUtils
        .parse(new URI(initialURI.get().getValue()), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

System.out.println(initialParams);
```

This results in:

```
[portal=myportal, LO=4, contentid=10007.786471, viewmode=content, variant=/myportal/]
```

### Note

This is not entirely your expected behavior, you expected `initialURI=https://example.com/dashboard/` to be in the list aswell. However you can see that this is *not* a query parameter, the entire url in `initialURI` (with it's query parameters) is the query parameter.