# Convert the request parameters in rest url to an object

Tags: java, rest

Is there any direct method to convert the HTTP request parameters to an object? (something like object mapper)

For example, if the request http://localhot:8080/users/id=5&name=10 httpHandler() then id=5&name=10 this needs to converted to User object

```
public class User {
         int id;
         String name;
         //getters and setters
}

class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
   @Override
   public void Handle(HttpExchange http) {
   String param = http.get.getRequestURI().getQuery();
   ?? // how to map it to the User Object?
   }
}
```

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: And what framework are you using?

Comment: You can easily turn query parameters to a `Map` then use `queryMap.get("id")` for example. More at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection

Answer (score 0):

[Spring](https://spring.io/) does this for you automatically with [RequestBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) annotation.

Say you make an HTTP POST request to URL http://localhost:8080/users/ with JSON request

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Bob"
}
```

You can map this request using Spring like so:

```
@POST
@Path("/users")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String users(@RequestBody User user) {
    // Value is "ID: 1, Name: Bob"
    return "ID: " + user.getId() + ", Name: " + user.getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring then [Here](http://dolszewski.com/spring/how-to-bind-requestparam-to-object/) is a very good example. You can annotate controller method with @GetMapping and pass a DTO object(that have all your request params as members) to method as an argument.