# Question about extracting parameter from URL inside WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, spring-boot, split, webdriver

I need help with extracting parameter from URL. I have used

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl()
```

to catch current URL.

After that, I need to extract value from the parameter called oauth_verifier from

```
http://localhost:4200/consent?oauth_token=something&oauth_verifier=something
```

so I can use it later in code.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse a URI String into Name-Value Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection)

Comment: Have you tried split strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This One , I Am not Sure Its Right Way , But Its Work...

```
String str = "http://localhost:4200/consent?oauth_token=something&oauth_verifier=something"; 
        String[] arrOfStr = str.split("/"); 
String temp=arrOfStr[3];
String temp2[]=temp.split("\\?|\\=");
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the *value* associated with `oauth_verifier` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* with *ExpectedConditions* as `urlContains()` the text **oauth_verifier** and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains("oauth_verifier"));
  String fullUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
  String[] UrlParts = fullUrl.split("=");
  System.out.println(UrlParts[2]);
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  something
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its Java ,you should use the substring function of String .

```
yourstring.substring(indexOf1stCharacter,indexOfLastCharacter)
```

For your case:

```
url.substring(url.indexOf("oauth_verifier=") + 15 , url.length());
```