# java class to parse URL with parameters?

Tags: java, url

Does java standard lib have a class to parse a URL string with query string(parameters)? e.g.,

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
Map<String,String> parameters = url.getParameters();
String value = url.getParameter(name);
```

But the standard URL class does not have knowledge of query string parameters.

Comment: Nope.  No such method exists at the moment.  There’s open bugs for it, such as https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6794192 and https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6306820.

Comment: If you decide to implement this yourself, note that the same parameter may appear in the query string multiple times. A better return type might be `Map<String, List<String>>` (or if you're lucky enough to be using Guava, `Multimap<String, String>`).

Comment: This anwser may help you: [parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection)