# Java : Map UrlEncoded String to Java Object

Tags: java

In a service call I'm am getting UrlEncoded String in response like :

```
first_name=ABC&last_name=XYZ&age=25&mob=999xxxxxxx&email=xxxxx@gmail.com&city=ABC&state=DEF&country=India
```

Now, I want the above string to be mapped to a Java Object having the variables name matching the keys from above UrlEncoded string.

It can be done by using delimiter "&" and parsing it to java variables one by one but I'm in search of any direct method or library available to do so because the string I'm recieving in response is large so, logically its not good to parse it one by one. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse a URI String into Name-Value Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection)

Answer (score 2):

```
List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

then init your object

```
Map<String, String> map = params.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(NameValuePair::getName, NameValuePair::getValue));

    YourObject yourObject = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(map, YourObject.class);
```