# Collect key values from array to map without duplicates

Tags: java

My app gets some string from web service. It's look like this:

```
name=Raul&city=Paris&id=167136
```

I want to get map from this string:

```
{name=Raul, city=Paris, id=167136}
```

Code:

```
Arrays.stream(input.split("&"))
          .map(sub -> sub.split("="))
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(string-> string[0]), string -> string[1]));
```

It's okay and works in most cases, but app can get a string with duplicate keys, like this:

```
name=Raul&city=Paris&id=167136&city=Oslo
```

App will crash with following uncaught exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key city (attempted merging values Paris and Oslo)
```

I tried to change *collect* method:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(tokens -> tokens[0], tokens -> tokens[1]), (r, strings) -> strings[0]);
```

But complier says no:

```
Cannot resolve method 'collect(java.util.stream.Collector<T,capture<?>,java.util.Map<K,U>>, <lambda expression>)'
```

And `Array type expected; found: 'T'`

I guess, it's because I have an array. How to fix it?

Comment: Why not use a library to parse query strings? Doing this by hand is a very bad idea as there a hundred corner cases your code misses! For example what about flags (properties without a value) or URL encoded data?

Comment: In the specific case though, simply use a custom merge strategy for your collector.

Comment: TL;DR: no, it doesn’t work in most cases are fixing this particular parsing issue leaves a multitude of others.

Comment: What kind of library to parse query? Can u provide a good example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse a URI String into Name-Value Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection)

Comment: This is not a real URI actually. It's just string with key/values similar to url query params.

Comment: @ChokkiAST It doesn't have to be a real URI, check the answers for code example and ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the final argument of `toMap` (the merge operator). When it find a duplicate key it hands the current value in the map and the new value with the same key to the merge operator which produces the single value to store.

For example, if you want to just store the first value found then use `(s1, s2) -> s1`. If you want to comma separate them, use `(s1, s2) -> s1 + ", " + s2`.

Comment: (although note that comma separation suggestion suffers from the string-concat-in-loop antipattern)

Comment: And the string-concat-in-loop antipattern suffers from the permature-optimisation antipattern :-)

Comment: On that I don’t agree. I think that quote is often misused - and I’m certain that is the case here. Especially being as there is a joining collector specifically to address this common issue.

Comment: I agree using a `groupingBy` with a downstream `joining` collector would make more sense in this case. However I disagree that string-concat-in-loop is often an antipattern. I've seen a lot of dumb code over the years that uses `StringBuilder` for theoretical performance improvements with no evidence that it is required in that particular case - but a lot of evidence that it makes the code much less readable.

Comment: Just to be clear - you have my upvote, this is the correct answer. We’re arguing over abstract theoreticals - and I totally agree that people can do stupid things with code regardless of how much the tooling tries to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add value of duplicated keys together and group them by key (*since app can get a string with duplicate keys*), instead of using `Collectors.toMap()` you can use a `Collectors.groupingBy` with custom collector (`Collector.of(...)`) :

```
String input = "name=Raul&city=Paris&city=Berlin&id=167136&id=03&id=505";

Map<String, Set<Object>> result = Arrays.stream(input.split("&"))
                .map(splitedString -> splitedString.split("="))
                .filter(keyValuePair -> keyValuePair.length() == 2)
                .collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(array -> array[0], Collector.of(
                                () -> new HashSet<>(), (set, array) -> set.add(array[1]),
                                (left, right) -> {
                                    if (left.size() < right.size()) {
                                        right.addAll(left);
                                        return right;
                                    } else {
                                        left.addAll(right);
                                        return left;
                                    }
                                }, Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED)
                        )
                );
```

This way you'll get :

```
result => size = 3
 "city" -> size = 2 ["Berlin", "Paris"]
 "name" -> size = 1 ["Raul"]
 "id"   -> size = 3 ["167136","03","505"]
```

Comment: Why not use a map collector with a duplicate key function? Isn’t the intent of that more obvious?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I prefer `Set<String>` rather than concatenating string like `s1 + "," + s2`, after all it depends on the need of the question author !

Comment: Yes, but a custom collector as you suggest is not required in any of those cases. And the author specifically asked just to take a single value - which is solved trivially with a custom merge function. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-

Comment: I didn't said it is required or it is the only solution, it could serve other people that are willing to have this behaviour instead of having a single value

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve the same result using kotlin `collections`

```
val res = message
        .split("&")
        .map {
            val entry = it.split("=")
            Pair(entry[0], entry[1])
        }
println(res)
println(res.toMap()) //distinct by key
```

**The result is**

[(name, Raul), (city, Paris), (id, 167136), (city, Oslo)]

{name=Raul, city=Oslo, id=167136}

Comment: This question is tagged Java.