# How do I validate a string format in Java?

Tags: java

I'm getting the following url string path for an example:
the following string url format `/version/mydownload?a=abc&b=bbb&c=ccc`
My question, how would validate? would you split `/` and `&` and then loop or is there a better way to validate?

my url string is not included `http` or `www` but it's part of the url string as shown above, would you split the string and check to see if this is in a right format?

Comment: The correct solution is to use a URL / URI parser; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/.  Validating URLs by hand is really tricky because of the various special cases that you need to deal with.

Comment: I have a specific string format(url) that need to validate if that string format is passed or not.

Comment: It’s always going to be the same format (url)

Comment: Using a parser is still the correct solution ... unless your benchmarking / profiling tells you that this validation *really* a performance bottleneck.  (Don't optimize prematurely ...)

Comment: @NickKahn Sorry, but what do you mean by validate? Are you trying to get a parameter, verify it's a valid url or...?

Comment: yes the key/value of the string, so for an example I just want to validate I have this format returns `/version/mydownload?a=abc&b=bbb&c=ccc` so the keys are `/version/mydownload` `a=abc` `b=bbb` `c=ccc` for an exaple.

Comment: @StephenP no it does not answer my question and again I'm not validating entire url, just validating part of a url string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure using a URL parser is a great way to parse URLs, but seeing as this really only requires some basic string splitting it seems like an overkill.

The following code should work:

```
String url = "/version/mydownload?a=abc&b=bbb&c=ccc";
int c1 = url.indexOf('?');
String path = c1 != -1 ? url.substring(0, c1) : url;
String[] keys = url.substring(c1+1).split("&");
System.out.println("Path: "+path+", keys: "+Arrays.toString(keys));
```

To extract the key value pairs, just split the String by `=` like so:

```
String firstKey = keys[0];
int c2 = firstKey.indexOf('=');
String key = firstKey.substring(0, c2);
String value = firstKey.substring(c2+1);
```

Which prints:

```
Path: /version/mydownload, keys: [a=abc, b=bbb, c=ccc]
```

Comment: It's more complicated than this. For instance, what comes after `?` must be key value pairs, the path before `?` must be a valid, well, path, etc.

Comment: @jingx To me it looked like all OP wanted to do was extract `/version/mydownload` `a=abc` `b=bbb` `c=ccc`, in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66773201/how-do-i-validate-a-string-format-in-java/66773548?noredirect=1#comment118035595_66773201)

Comment: Yeah but when people start and end their narrative with "for example", you don't really know what exactly the rules or possible inputs are. I doubt OP knows either, all the more reason to go with a URL parser.