# how to convert a String of http request parameters to a List<NameValuePair>

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have a String like

```
String input = "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=complexScope";
```

and I'd like to parse and then add these request parameters to  a List of NameValuePair of Apache commons.

I have created this function, which technically works through String splits.

```
public static  List<NameValuePair> stringToNameValuePair(String input) {
return Arrays.stream(input.split("&"))
        .map(pair -> new NameValuePair(pair.split("=")[0], pair.split("=")[1]))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

which seems to do the job for simple things, but I wonder if there is something already built-in and more tested in java or in any known library.

Comment: Does this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13592567/2478398 give you an appropriate method without a library.  If you want to use a library, `spring-web` provides `UriComponentsBuilder` which would return a `MultiValueMap<String, String>` using `UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("?a=b&c=d").build().getQueryParams();`

Comment: @BeUndead it is close, thanks. in this case I do not have the whole URL, I could use the solutions listed there by appending a URL.

Comment: It looks like you could just skip to the bit with `query = url.getQuery();` part, and use your `input` variable in that's place through the rest of the method calls.

Comment: It also appears you're trying to reimplement OAuth2, which you should _also_ be using a library (or entire stack) for.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- yeah.. it is not what it seems......