# How to get values from Uri parameters in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using Uri builder for building Uri with my parameters in this way:

```
Uri.Builder()
    .scheme("https")
    .authority("www.myawesomesite.com")
    .appendPath("turtles")
    .appendPath("types")
    .appendQueryParameter("type", "1")
    .appendQueryParameter("sort", "relevance")
    .fragment("section-name");
    .build()
```

It's fine and convinient way. But is there way how to teardown this Uri to get parameters from queries? To get "1" and "relevance" values parameters?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection) help?

Comment: @TylerV i will give it a try thanks