# Java - how to build an URI using a query string that is already escaped?

Tags: java, uri, apache-httpclient-4.x

LATER EDIT: not same problem as [the suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection). In my case, I **need to build the URI, relying on the fact that the original query string is not modified**.

---

I have a `String` (coming from a request query String) that is already correctly escaped, like `param1=%2Ffolder1%2Ffolder2%2Ffolder%26name%202&param2=9481dxcv234`.

The decoded value of `param1` is `/folder1/folder2/folder&name 2`. Obviously, I cannot unescape that String (because of the `&` char in this value)...

I need to build an URI which has **that original string** as query value.

I tried using `org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder` but could not get it to work: if I provide the **original** String to the `URI(...` constructor, the resulting URL is double-escaped, like `param1=%252Ffolder1%252Ffolder2%252Ffolder%2526name%25202&param2=9481dxcv234`.

Can I somehow do what I need ? To build an URI by passing the query string **already escaped** and leave it unchanged ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse a URI String into Name-Value Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection)

Comment: Not really...
I need to build the URI, **relying** that the query string does not get changed...

Answer (score 0):

I think, the simplest way is unescape it first.
Then you can work with url as usualy.

Comment: I can't, as the `&` char in the value of first param would then prevent correct parsing of parameters.
It should **not** be unescaped at this moment, one should unescape the query string **after** it was broken down in parameters...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder`:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url);
UriComponents components = builder.build(true); //EDIT: pass true when the URI was fully encoded already.
MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters = components.getQueryParams();

parameters.get("param1") //"%2Ffolder1%2Ffolder2%2Ffolder%26name%202"
```

You can then URLDecode to get what you need.

Edit:

Since you appear to be using Apache HttpClient,

```
List<NameValuePair> params = org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

params.get("param1") //"/folder1/folder2/folder&name 2"
```

Comment: this **_almost_** works: when I build back the URI, it has "+" for space, instead of "%20" ... :)

Comment: A simple replacement could take care of that - `decodedValue = decodedValue.replace('+', ' ');`
Also, try passing `true` to the build method, for when the URI was already fully encoded, as it seems is the case here.

Comment: Just tried with passing 'true' and that seems to work. Have amended my answer.