# Creating a URI from URL

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a URI from a URL for my Android application.

I've found the answer here [How to create a Uri from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240139/how-to-create-a-uri-from-a-url) but sadly, I am getting an exception

```
java.net.MalformedURLException
```

My code is

```
URL connection_url = new URL("http://www.google.com"); // exception on this line
URI uri = url.toURI();
```

I am importing the following

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong

**Edit**

Updated from www.google.com to http://www.google.com - same error

Comment: What else does the error say?

Comment: Did you really write `hpttp:`? This indeed gives a `MalformedURLException`

Comment: Sorry @Henry, no, that was a typo

Comment: Again, post the full stack trace with the full error message.

Comment: Or is it a compiler error?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"www.google.com"` not a valid URL as it misses the protocol part. Try something like:

```
URL connection_url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
```

For example this works without problems:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException {
    URL connection_url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
    URI uri = connection_url.toURI();
    System.out.println(uri);
}
```

Comment: Copying and pasting the code still fails in the same manner I describe above, until I do the throws MalformedURLExpcetion, URISyntaxException

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
Uri uri =  Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
```