# Android URL to Uri

Tags: android

I have to change URL to URI, please guide me how can I change it.

I have tried a lot, but not getting the solution.  Any help is appreciated. I can also attach code snippet if required.

Comment: see this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593214/android-howto-parse-url-string-with-spaces-to-uri-object

Answer (score 125):

We can parse any URL using Uri.parse(String) method.

**Code Snippet :**

```
Uri uri =  Uri.parse( "http://www.stackoverflow.com" );
```

Comment: Well that would be String to Uri, not URL to Uri.

Comment: should `java.net.URI` be used or `android.net.Uri` ? Is there a preference ?

Answer (score 35):

```
final String myUrlStr = "xyz";
URL url;
Uri uri;
try {
    url = new URL(myUrlStr);
    uri = Uri.parse( url.toURI().toString() );
} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: At first glance that answer looks convoluted. Why convert to string and then parse? The reason is that `toURI()` returns a `java.net.URI`. So we need to map to string and then parse into `android.net.Uri`. Good answer

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin you can use this code snippet:

```
            val uri = Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my 2 Cents , it could help someone else.

The standard URL Parsing might not be good idea if you have variables passed to the URL as Query

```
String your_url_which_is_not_going_to_change = "http://stackoverflow.com/?q="
String your_query_string = "some other stuff"
String query = null;

try {
  query = URLEncoder.encode(your_query_string, "utf-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}

String url = your_url_which_is_not_going_to_change + query;

URL input = new URL(url);
etc... .
```

Hope it helps.

H.

Comment: he is asking to parse URL to URI however you are only parsing the URL

Answer (score 0):

var url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/(mymobileapp)/login.php";

var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: data);