# how to replace space with %20 in url in android in jsonparsing

Tags: java

In my application i want to replace space with %20 in my string.I tried in this way,

```
String flag1="http://74.208.194.142/admin/upload_image/1342594079_images (2).jpg";
flag1.replaceAll("", "%20");
```

But it is not working please help me.I am getting null pointer exception.

Comment: This is not android. This is java. Very basic java.

Answer (score 10):

You should do it like:

```
flag1 = flag1.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

first you were putting empty string instead of space..
and second you must return the value into the `flag1` variable..

Comment: please help me where i did mistake suggest me where i need to change

Comment: flag1 = flag1.replaceAll(" ", "%20"); should work

Comment: check also http://stackoverflow.com/a/2593319/1434631

Comment: i tried that also but i am getting null pointer exception

Comment: What did you try?  The only way that `flag1 = flag1.replaceAll(" ", "%20");` can give an NPE is if `flag1` was null to start with.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

It is not only the blanks that need to be replaced. URLs consist of special caracters for special meanings (e.g. the question mark to start the query string)

```
String flag1 = URLEncoder.encode("This string has spaces", "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Not sure why this is even voted up, OP is replacing path arguments, not query params, URLEncoder encodes " " to "+" not "%20"

Comment: This will add + not %20

Answer (score 4):

In `flag1.replaceAll()`, your space is missing. try:

```
String flag1="http://74.208.194.142/admin/upload_image/1342594079_images (2).jpg";
flag1 = flag1.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

and set the result to the flag1.

Answer (score 4):

```
    String flag1="http://74.208.194.142/admin/upload_image/1342594079_images (2).jpg";
    URI uri = null;
    try {
        uri = new URI(flag1.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(uri);
```

The console will display output as

`http://74.208.194.142/admin/upload_image/1342594079_images%20(2).jpg`