# GET Request Encoding issue

Tags: android, utf-8, get, encode, url-encoding

So I need to parse input from my android application and make a GET request on a website, example: `www.example.com/profile/'profile nickname'`

So when I use URL encoder:

```
URLEncoder.encode(nickname, "utf-8");
```

It parses the blank space as `'+'`, but I want to parse it as `%20`, because that specifically API requires `%20` instead of `+`. Plus all those unusuall characters to parse with the similar form as `'%20'`.

And when I use dot('.') in my GET request the URLEncoder does not parse it as "%2E", instead it passes it as ".".Any solutions?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3286128/3946958

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671450/how-to-replace-space-with-20-in-url-in-android-in-jsonparsing