# why android throwing error when the query string element of url is having white space in it

Tags: android, url

I am having the following url, which was using in my application

```
url = "http://ip/somefile.py?name=Adithya g&age=15&address=Trichy Tamilnadu"
```

when i am going to parse the above string in either httpget or httppost using android. I am getting error. suppose if the url is modified as the following

```
url  ="http://ip/somefile.py?name=Adithya%20g&age=15&address=Trichy%20Tamilnadu"
```

the url is working fine. Where was the mistake? whether it is mistake of that particular server or the android development side.

Comment: The space basically breaks the url so you need to encode the url.

Comment: Ok guys. Thanks for the Reply.. I used string.replaceAll("\\s","%20"). As i am having only one white space parameter. I used it.

Comment: @TortoiseWalker You should use UrlEncode,anyway enjoy coding.

Comment: hmmm... really enjoying in android with the help of all of you.

Answer (score 1):

You should in fact [`URLEncode`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) the ["invalid" characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).For more info see [Url encoding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android)

Or use like

```
   String url = Uri.parse("http://ip/somefile.py")
                    .buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter("key", "val")
                    .build().toString();
```

Where key= parameter name, val = parameter value.

Or this [Android: howto parse URL String with spaces to URI object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593214/android-howto-parse-url-string-with-spaces-to-uri-object)

Comment: I didn't know about URLEncoder, in my app I naively did String querystring="some string with space" and then did querystring=querystring.replace(" ", "%20"); This seems like a much more complete and trustable approach. +1d But what could be possible drawbacks of my method compared to this?

Comment: You should use the URLEncoder class, to encode the params you want to pass with your URL. Just replacing the spaces isn't the best idea and should not even be suggested.