# Uri.parse string with spaces doesn't work

Tags: android

I'm trying to parse a link that conatins spaces, but the Uri.parse method doesn't work on that...
Any idea why does it happen and how to fix this?

Comment: please post code if you really try

Comment: `why does it happen?` because you have a space in your Uri `how to fix this?` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: You can add %20 in place of spaces as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593214/android-howto-parse-url-string-with-spaces-to-uri-object