# Picasso not working if url contains space

Tags: android, url, picasso

I am developing an Android app in which I am retrieving an image from a server and show it in an image view using Picasso. Some image URLs don't work even though I can test them successfully in a browser.

For example this URL works correctly:

```
http://www.tonightfootballreport.com/\Filebucket\Picture\image\png\20160730011032_BPL.png
```

But this one fails:

```
http://www.tonightfootballreport.com/\Filebucket\Picture\image\png\20160807025619_Serie A.png
```

The difference appears to be that the failing URL contains a space. What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: replace all spaces with `%20`. Would you like to see a code sample? then I can post an answer.

Comment: @Wai Yan Hein try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2593319/3117966) out :)

Comment: Simply encode your url or just check that your url contains space or not.

Comment: Thanks @IshitaSinha. It worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
String temp = "http://www.tonightfootballreport.com/\Filebucket\Picture\image\png\20160807025619_Serie A.png";
temp = temp.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
URL sourceUrl = new URL(temp);
```

Comment: The actual solution is to encode the URL like the other answer suggests. This answer only encodes spaces, but not all other characters which need to be encoded.

Comment: if your url contains non English words, this answer won't work!

Comment: Hmm... He is asking only spaces.

Comment: That doesn't change that this is a bad answer. He is asking for spaces because he has only encountered the problem with spaces. The op obviously doesn't know about url encoding etc and giving him/her this half solution that appears to work is like a bug timebomb itching to explode.

Answer (score 7):

Encode the URL,

```
String url = "http://www.tonightfootballreport.com/Filebucket/Picture/image/png/20160807025619_Serie A.png";
String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "utf-8");
```

**EDIT #1 :**

The problem with above method as @Wai Yan Hein, pointed is that it encode all the characters in the url including the protocol.

The following code solves that issue,

```
String urlStr = "http://www.tonightfootballreport.com/Filebucket/Picture/image/png/20160807025619_Serie A.png";
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
url = uri.toURL();
```

**Edit #2**

Alternate solution using `Uri.parse`,

```
String urlStr = "http://www.tonightfootballreport.com/Filebucket/Picture/image/png/20160807025619_Serie A.png";
String url = Uri.parse(urlStr)
                .buildUpon()
                .build()
                .toString();
```

Comment: Url become like this, http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tonightfootballreport.com%2F%5CFilebucket%5CPicture%5Cimage%5Cpng%5C20160730011032_BPL.png and all not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the URL is indeed valid and if not try encoding it,

```
if(!Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches()){
            URLEncoder.encode(url, "utf-8");
            //Now load via Picasso
        }
else{
      //Proceed with loading via picasso
}
```