# Android Retrofit appends unwanted characters

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am trying to do a GET request to a json file:

https://www.someurl.com/appconfiguration.json

So I created an Interface with the following GET method

```
  @GET("appconfiguration.json}")
  Call<AppConfigParent> loadAppConfigParent();
```

and call it like this:

```
   final MMSATServices.AppConfigResponse appConfigResponse = new MMSATServices.AppConfigResponse();
    appConfigResponse.appConfigParent = new AppConfigParent();
    appConfigResponse.appConfigParent.configuration = null;

    Call<AppConfigParent> call = api.loadAppConfigParent();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<AppConfigParent>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<AppConfigParent> call, Response<AppConfigParent> response) {
            appConfigResponse.appConfigParent.configuration = response.body().configuration;
            bus.post(appConfigResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<AppConfigParent> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

note that the `api` object is the instance of the interface, whichis defined in the super class.

The actual problem is that I get a 404 repsonse:

Request{method=GET, url=https://someurl.com/appconfiguration.json%7D, tag=Request{method=GET, url=https://someurl.com/appconfiguration.json%7D, tag=null}}

As you can see `%7D` is appended to the URL, which leads to the 404 error. How can I get rid of this behavior?

Comment: change @GET("appconfiguration.json}") to @GET("appconfiguration.json")

Comment: I will just leave in shame

Comment: try to get the hint from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593214/android-howto-parse-url-string-with-spaces-to-uri-object

Comment: @4ndro1d you save my ass bro!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `}` in `@GET("appconfiguration.json}")`