# How to escape angular HttpParams?

Tags: angular, http

In an Angular Service I'm using HttpParams to send a string to the service:

```
get(phone: string): Observable<PhoneSearchResponse> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append("phone", phone); // sending "+123456"
    return this._http.get<PhoneSearchResponse>(`${this._apiurl}/Get`, { params: params });
}
```

When calling get() with `+123456` as parameter I'll get `123456` in the receiving service. So somewhere on the way the `+` gets converted to a space.

Do I need to escape HttpParams to get them unchanged to the service?

If it matters, the backend is an asp.net core project. The called code in the controller:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<JsonResult> Get(string phone) // receiving " 123456"
{
  return Json(await PhoneSearchLogic.GetAsync(phone));
}
```

[Update] Very good explanation by Noémi Salaün - but I wonder if changing the parameters is expecteded behaviour "by design"? Or is the problem the ASP.NET Core controller, which should not unescape the + sign (and others)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular url plus sign converting to space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428842/angular-url-plus-sign-converting-to-space)

Comment: Seems related, yes. But shouldn't HttpParams escape the + sign?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As you can see in the source code [common/http/src/params.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.9/packages/common/http/src/params.ts#L106), `HttpParams` uses a default encoder `HttpUrlEncodingCodec`.

`HttpUrlEncodingCodec` uses the native `encodeURIComponent` function but then un-encodes some symbole to meet the RFC specification (not followed by the native JS implementation).

So if you want to keep your `+` symbol encoded you can encode it manually before using `HttpParams`, or you can override the `HttpParameterCodec` with your own implementation and pass it through the `HttpParamOptions.encoder` attribute.

All this was better explained in the now deprecated `Http` service. With its `UrlSearchParams` and the `QueryEncoder`.

As you can see in the source code [http/src/url_search_params.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.9/packages/http/src/url_search_params.ts#54)

> By default, `QueryEncoder` encodes keys and values of parameters using `encodeURIComponent`, and then un-encodes certain characters that are allowed to be part of the query according to IETF RFC 3986: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.
>
> These are the characters that are not encoded: `! $ \' ( ) * + , ; A 9 - . _ ~ ? /`
>
> If the set of allowed query characters is not acceptable for a particular backend, `QueryEncoder` can be subclassed and provided as the 2nd argument to URLSearchParams.

Comment: That explains a lot - so, according to RFC specs, this replacement is "by design", even though it changes the data I get at the service end? Or is the Service the problem and should not unescape the + sign?

Comment: It doesn't change the data. If you look at the console when sending the request, you'll see the `+`. Some backend understand a `+` inside an URL, as an escaped space. Like the Angular team said, if a particular backend does not follow the RFC, you can provide your `HttpParameterCodec` that best fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, it explains a lot. I'll check if I try to 'fix' the backend or create my own encoder as parameter.

Comment: This should be in the Angular documentation. It is quite a surprise to see your + character remains unchanged when you expect it to be encoded. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Angular 13 still has this problem. Look at
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11058  and
https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/45111
The solution that worked for me was written by Ali Kamalizade  at
https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-fix-angular-httpclient-not-escaping-url-parameters-ddce3f9b8746
The following is his solution. The same solution was suggested by Noémi Salaün in the accepted answer of this question.

```
import { HttpParameterCodec } from '@angular/common/http';
export class CustomHttpParamEncoder implements HttpParameterCodec {
    encodeKey(key: string): string {
        return encodeURIComponent(key);
    }
    encodeValue(value: string): string {
            return encodeURIComponent(value);
    }
    decodeKey(key: string): string {
            return decodeURIComponent(key);
    }
    decodeValue(value: string): string {
            return decodeURIComponent(value);
    }
}
```

You can use it when you create a HttpParams.

```
 new HttpParams({ encoder: new CustomHttpParamEncoder() })
```

EDIT:
This was fixed in version 14. See
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#http-1
https://blog.angular.io/angular-v14-is-now-available-391a6db736af

Answer (score -4):

Rather a pure Javascript solution,

```
const string = 'text+that+has+plus+signs';
```

To encode safely, (please note `encodeURIComponent` is important as `btoa` can return `+`)

```
const enc = encodeURIComponent(btoa(string));
console.log(enc); //dGV4dCt0aGF0K2hhcytwbHVzK3NpZ25z
```

To decode and get the plain text back,

```
const dec = atob(decodeURIComponent(enc));    
console.log(dec); //text+that+has+plus+signs
```

I am not really a fan of overriding the `HttpUrlEncodingCodec` just to escape `+` signs in the post parameters.

I hope this will help someone. Cheers :)

Answer (score -5):

I ran into this issue some time ago, and finally resolved to use FormData instead of HttpParams... almost everywhere. I used to rely on FormData especially when sending files to a service, until I sent a string with the + symbol in it using HttpParams, and + never got to the backend; it got replaced by a space.

So just replace

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append("phone", phone); // sending "+123456"
```

with

```
let params = new FormData();
params.append("phone", phone);
```