# How to stop converting + symbols into space in Angular

Tags: angular, angular5

searchItem Contain some value like abc+def. when i am checking in backend its going like (abc def). how to fixed .+(plus sign convert into space)

```
search(searchItem: string): Promise<any> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('searchItem', searchItem);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // use For Testing
        this.httpClient.get(this.urlService.getApiUrl() + 'test/item',
                {
                    params: params
                })
        .subscribe(data => {
            resolve(data);
        }, error => {
            console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular url plus sign converting to space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428842/angular-url-plus-sign-converting-to-space)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `encodeURIComponent()` method before set param.

```ts
...
params = params.append('searchItem', encodeURIComponent(searchItem));
...
```

Comment: yeah i already use encodeURI() and encodeURIComponent() no one is working .Still printing  ABC%2BDEF

Comment: That is working correctly. You have to decode it in your back-end app.

Comment: I am using spring JPA .can you tell me where i have to decode

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom encoder for `HttpParams` to fix this.

```
import { HttpParameterCodec } from '@angular/common/http';

export class CustomEncoder implements HttpParameterCodec {
  encodeKey(key: string): string {
    return encodeURIComponent(key);
  }

  encodeValue(value: string): string {
    return encodeURIComponent(value);
  }

  decodeKey(key: string): string {
    return decodeURIComponent(key);
  }

  decodeValue(value: string): string {
    return decodeURIComponent(value);
  }
}
```

and then in your `search()` function,

```
let params = new HttpParams({encoder: new CustomEncoder()});
```