# Angular 8 routerLinks create decoded href with # to %23

Tags: html, angular, routerlink

I have one problem with generating routerLinks in my application.
I retrieve the menu structure from API. Fetch it when app initializes, store it in the Observable and then simply show it.

The part of the structure im showing is pretty straightforward.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
  <h5 class="dekstop-submenu-heading">{{ item.name }}</h5>
    <ul class="desktop-submenu-list" [ngClass]="{'desktop-submenu-list-wrap': item.subItems.length > 5}">
      <li *ngFor="let subItem of item.subItems" class="desktop-submenu-item">
        <a [attr.aria-label]="subItem.name" [routerLink]="subItem.url">{{ subItem.name }}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</ng-container>
```

The problem comes when there is an url with an anchor to specific page part, i.e. `/some-component/description#specific`.
Angular routerLink is generated properly but the href isn't, it is decoded to `/some-component/description%23specific.`
I can't get rid of this behaviour, I've tried decoding it with decodeURIComponent but with no effects..

Do you have any idea what causes such behaviour? Such a simply thing makes a lot of troubles..

Comment: see this  https://stackoverflow.com/q/45428842/5366038

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to send the `url` and the `element id` in a separate directive.

If you have control over the `subItem.url` then just rename it to `/description` and `subItem.fragment` to `specific` and then change the template like this:

```
[routerLink]="subItem.url" [fragment]="subItem.fragment"
```

If you don't have control over `subItem.url`, then just perform a split on `%23`:

```
const [url, ...fragment] = subItem.url.split('%23');

[routerLink]="url" [fragment]="fragent.join('%23')"
```

Comment: Thanks. You suggestion with splitting up the url was the best.

Comment: @mmied I noticed a problem re-reading my answer. I'll update it soon

Answer (score 0):

You can handle query params in routerLink directive
I think this will help you

```
  <a [attr.aria-label]="subItem.name" [routerLink]="subItem.url" 
      queryParamsHandling="preserve">{{ subItem.name }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced @[Christian Vincenzo Traina's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1850851/christian-vincenzo-traina) Answer

Use fragments if encode, decode or any other URI doesn't work

**Here is the sample code**

```
if (this.relativeInternalUrl.includes('+')) {
    this.router.navigate([this.relativeInternalUrl?.split('+')[0]], {
      fragment: this.relativeInternalUrl?.split('+')[1],
    });
  } else {
    this.router.navigate([this.relativeInternalUrl]);
  }
```

Hope this helps!!!