# Angular API call with double quotation marks

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have service where I call API URL and my URL supposed to have `".."` quotation mark around my values but it prints like `%22%27` when I call the API, **How can I have my double quotation marks as they are in my URL?**

#### Code

```
return this.http
      .get(`${this.env.HELPDESK_LIST_FILTER}` + '[{ "value": ' + `'"${value}"'` + ', "field": ' + `'"${column}"'` + ', "sort": ' + `'"${sort}"'` + ', "op": ' + `'"${filter}"'` + ' }]', params)
      .pipe(map((data) => data));
```

My final URL supposed to be like this:

```
https://example.com/api/tickets?filters=[{"value":"una","field":"name","sort":"none","op":"like"}]
```

Instead it's like this now:

```
https://example.com/api/tickets?filters=[{%20%22value%22:%20%27%22una%22%27,%20%22field%22:%20%27%22name%22%27,%20%22sort%22:%20%27%22none%22%27,%20%22op%22:%20%27%22like%22%27%20}]
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428842/angular-url-plus-sign-converting-to-space

Comment: @Sajeetharan not helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
    return this.http
          .get(`${this.env.HELPDESK_LIST_FILTER}[{ "value": "${value}", "field": "${column}", "sort": "${sort}", "op": "${filter}" }]`, params)
          .pipe(map((data) => data));
```

Comment: its the same also dynamic values needs to be covered in double quotation.

Comment: you don't need to concatenate with '+'  inside template literals

Comment: you can use double quotation, try the code

Comment: Hi, I am following your answer for other url it doesn't work on that! `.get(`${this.env.HELPDESK_SEARCH}["${value}"], &fields=["ticket__number","name","status__name"]`, params)`

Comment: Remember to add the backticks(at the start and end)